# A package template using xkeyval?

Tags: package-writing, key-value, package-options, xkeyval

I would like to write a package offering a number of commands. The package should accept options, and some of these options should be available as command options. Usage should be as follows:

```
...
\usepackage[optA=val1,optB=val2]{mypackage}
\begin{document}
\mycommand[optB=val3]
...
```

It seems as if the `xkeyval` package can do that, but I am not sure how this should be done exactly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me provide a simple (but full) example:

```
\ProvidesPackage{myemph}[2011/03/12 v1.0 a test package]

\providecommand\my@emphstyle{\em}

% Note that the argument must be expandable,
% or use xkvltxp package before \documentclass (see manual of xkeyval)
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{style}{%
  \def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
% predefined styles
\providecommand\my@style@default{\em}
\providecommand\my@style@bold{\bfseries}

\ProcessOptionsX

% For simple key-value commands, keyval would suffie
\define@key{myemph}{code}{%
  \def\my@emphstyle{#1}}
\define@key{myemph}{style}{%
  \def\my@emphstyle{\csname my@style@#1\endcsname}}
\newcommand\setemph[1]{%
  \setkeys{myemph}{#1}}

\renewcommand\emph[1]{%
  {\my@emphstyle #1}}

\endinput
```

Test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=default]{myemph}

\begin{document}
Something \emph{important}

\setemph{style=bold}
Something \emph{important}

\setemph{code=\Large\sffamily}
Something \emph{important}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have read this article http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros which lead me to this post. Can you explain what `\providecommand\my@emphstyle{\em}` does? I know the command `\providecommand` but I cant find what the `@`means. Also, if I do a regular short document and including just this line in the preamble, my document wont compile.

Comment: @Adam: You may read [`\@` and `@` in macro names](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=atsigns)

Comment: @Adam: See also, for example, [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Answer (score 21):

Accepting key-value input can be done using a number of packages, and the general approach is the same for all of them: I covered this in some detail in a [TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94wright-keyval.pdf). Essentially, there are three things you need to do

1. Define one or more keys;
2. Tell LaTeX to process package options using these keys;
3. Provide a macro for setting keys after package loading.

In the question, you've mentioned the [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval/) package, with others including [`kvoptions`](http://ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions), [`pgfkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys) (plus [`pgfopts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts/)) and the LaTeX3 keys system [`l3keys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) (plus [`l3keys2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpackages/)). I have used all of these in the past, and I would favour `pgfkeys` (if you do not want to use LaTeX3) or the LaTeX3 keys implementation (if you are happy using `expl3`). The reason is that these two have in my opinion the best overall method for defining keys. (I should add that I wrote most of the LaTeX3 keys system, and this was based initially on the `pgfkeys` approach.)

As the question asks for an `xkeyval` approach, I will sketch one out here. First, of course, you'll need to load the package.

```
\usepackage{xkeyval}
```

This also loads the parent `keyval` package, which provides some of the basic mechaism. To define keys, the basic macro is `\define@key`:

```
\define@key{mypkg}{optA}{<code for optA>} % 'mypkg' is the 'family' for the keys
\define@key{mypkg}{optB}{<code for optB>}
```

Within the code, `#1` will be the value passed to the key. You can define key types with richer validation (for example Boolean keys) using the various `xkeyval` macros. As I say, the `xkeyval` approach is rather dense, and I think 'one question per key type' might be best if you want more information!

The second stage is to process the package options. To do this, in place of `\ProcessOptions` you use `\ProcessOptionsX<mypkg>`. This will work through the package options, looking for a defined key for each one and executing the code it finds.

Finally, to define a macro to use the keys after package loading, you need `\setkeys`:

```
\newcommand\mymacro[1]{\setkeys{mypkg}{#1}}
```

What you should notice here is that key-value package options are just keys that are defined when the `\ProcessOptionsX` macro is used. So it is possible to define keys only as package options, then disable them by doing `\defin@key` again. It's also possible to define options that are only available *after* package loading, by simply placing `\define@key` after `\ProcessOptionsX`.

Comment: A small correction: they should be `\define@key<mypkg>{optA}{<code for optA>}` and `\ProcessOptionsX<mypkg>`

Comment: @Leo: been a while since I used `xkeyval`: I'll update that.

Comment: @Leo: I'm sure I'm right on `\define@key`, as the syntax comes from the `keyval` package!

Comment: sorry I thought it was \DeclareOptionX

Answer (score 3):

An example with some code from the documentation

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[12/03/2011]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\DeclareOptionX{parindent}[20pt]{\setlength\parindent{#1}} 
\ExecuteOptionsX{parindent=0pt}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax 
% etc.
\endinput
```

`\DeclareOptionX` is equivalent to (thanks to Ahmed Musa for the correction)

```
\define@key{mypackage.sty}{parindent}[20pt]{\setlength\parindent{#1}}
```

Comment: You have mixed package and class calls. In your case, `\DeclareOptionX` is equivalent to `\define@key{mypackage.sty}{parindent}[20pt]{\setlength\parindent{#1}}`.