# How to create a command with key values?

Tags: macros, key-value

I am trying to create a command that the user can enter keys for values. How can I create one, for example:

```
 \myparbox[width=50,height=10,color=blue, align=left -10px]{}
```

Comment: If you already have code that does this, a `\newcommand` will allow you to wrap it up in the way you want above.

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/a-package-template-using-xkeyval/13273#13273

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Use [`pgfkeys`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys)!  There are three steps to this: first, you must make your command accept keys as options.  Traditionally, this is as you wrote it: an optional argument.  In that case, you should start your definition like this:

```
\newcommand\myparbox[2][]{%
 \pgfkeys{#1}%
 ...
}
```

The syntax is that the optional argument is expected to contain a list of keys (possibly set to values) that are then passed to `\pgfkeys` for processing.  The second step is to figure out what you're going to do with the results: that is, you imagine that `\pgfkeys` does some kind of magic and produces a bunch of macros, or conditionals, and you need to make these things affect the operation of `\myparbox`.

Let's take the easy ones as an example: `width` and `height`.  You will probably just pass them to `\parbox` as the optional parameters that control the width and height, and a good way to do that is to store their values in a macro.  Let's say that `width` goes to the macro `\myparboxWidth` and `height` goes to `\myparboxHeight`.  Then your definition of `\myparbox` will look more like:

```
\newcommand\myparbox[2][]{%
 \pgfkeys{#1}%
 \parbox[t][\myparboxHeight]{\myparboxWidth}{#2}%
}
```

I had to write `[t]` for the first optional argument in `\parbox`, which specifies the position in the surrounding text, because height is the second argument.  This suggests that we ought to have a `position` key as well that corresponds to a macro `\myparboxPosition`.  There's a third optional argument that I didn't give, but it's the "inner position", which can be either top, bottom, centered, or stretched.  Might as well have an `inner position` key that sets `\myparboxInnerPos`.  That gives:

```
\newcommand\myparbox[2][1]{%
 \pgfkeys{#1}%
 \parbox[\myparboxPosition][\myparboxHeight]
        [\myparboxInnerPos]{\myparboxWidth}{#2}
}
```

That's enough for now.  In order to make this work, you have to define your keys, and that's where `pgfkeys` is far, far better than its competitors.  You can tell it to do all sorts of things with the values other than just storing them, though for `height` and `width` that will be enough.  You define keys by using `\pgfkeys` in the preamble to set things up:

```
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
 /myparbox/.is family, /myparbox,
 width/.estore in = \myparboxWidth,
 height/.estore in = \myparboxHeight,
}
```

This has a few features.  The real action is that I've said that both of these keys will "pass through" their arguments to the respective macros; if you said "width = 10pt" in the options to `\myparbox`, then `\myparboxWidth` would get set to `10pt`.  I wrote `.estore in` rather than plain `.store in` to force the value to be expanded before being saved; this prevents subtle errors if someone passes a macro that could get changed somehow before being used in `\myparbox`.

The other feature is that I've put the keys in a family, called `/myparbox`.  In `pgfkeys` jargon, this is a "directory", like in a file system.  Calling the `/myparbox` key changes directory to this one, and then all keys are private to that directory.  This prevents name clashes with the (very common) key names `width` and `height`.  Now you have to modify your `\pgfkeys` call in `\myparbox` as well to change directory:

```
\newcommand\myparbox[2][1]{%
 \pgfkeys{/myparbox, #1}%
 ...
}
```

For the position arguments, it would be nice if they could have more...logical names than simply "t", "b", "c", or "s".  Since `pgfkeys` is, at heart, a lookup engine, it is pretty easy to have it map logical names to various actions: you just make each name a key that points to the corresponding action.  I would do the following:

```
\pgfkeys{
 /myparbox,
 position/.style = {positions/#1/.get = \myparboxPosition},
 inner position/.style = {positions/#1/.get = \myparboxInnerPos},
 positions/.cd,
  top/.initial = t,
  center/.initial = c,
  bottom/.initial = b,
  stretch/.initial = s,
}
```

This is *much* more intricate than `width` and `height`, so I'll take it apart.

- First, we have the basic `position` and `inner position` keys, which are passed values.  `\pgfkeys` treats these keys like macros with one argument, so the value is available as `#1`.  We tell them to store the values in the appropriate place.  The `/.style` suffix is a "handler" that defines a more complex behavior for a key than just setting a value; in this case, it makes the key "expand" to other keys that are then called to continue the work.
- What gets stored, though, has to be properly formatted: `\parbox` expects those one-character options and not words.  So we define a `positions` subdirectory containing all the words we want to accept, defined to contain their translations into `\parbox`-speak.  (As before, we isolate these special keys in a directory where they can't be seen and won't conflict with real options.) The `/.initial` handler sets values for keys the first time they are seen (these keys will never be redefined, actually).
- Back in `position` and `inner position`, the way we actually store the values is by using the `/.get` handler for the appropriate `positions/` subkey.  What this does is simply copy the value in that key into the named macro, which is what we wanted: `position = top` becomes `\def\myparboxPosition{t}` (effectively).

There is *one* more complication to take care of: what happens if you only specify half the options?  The remaining macros `\myparboxWhatever` will be undefined or, more insidiously, defined to be whatever they got set to the last time they called `\myparbox`.  We need to establish some defaults.  The easiest way of doing that is to make a `default` style key that we run before processing the options in `\myparbox`.  It may look like this:

```
\pgfkeys{
 /myparbox,
 default/.style = 
  {width = \textwidth, height = \baselineskip,
   position = center, inner position = center}
}
```

Then the `\pgfkeys` call in `\myparbox` becomes

```
\pgfkeys{/myparbox, default, #1}
```

Here is the final result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

% Set up the keys.  Only the ones directly under /myparbox
% can be accepted as options to the \myparbox macro.
\pgfkeys{
 /myparbox/.is family, /myparbox,
 % Here are the options that a user can pass
 default/.style = 
  {width = \textwidth, height = \baselineskip,
   position = center, inner position = center},
 width/.estore in = \myparboxWidth,
 height/.estore in = \myparboxHeight,
 position/.style = {positions/#1/.get = \myparboxPosition},
 inner position/.style = {positions/#1/.get = \myparboxInnerPos},
 % Here is the dictionary for positions.
 positions/.cd,
  top/.initial = t,
  center/.initial = c,
  bottom/.initial = b,
  stretch/.initial = s,
}

% We process the options first, then pass them to `\parbox` in the form of macros.
\newcommand\myparbox[2][]{%
 \pgfkeys{/myparbox, default, #1}%
 \parbox[\myparboxPosition][\myparboxHeight]
        [\myparboxInnerPos]{\myparboxWidth}{#2}
}

\begin{document}
 % This should print "Some text, and"
 % followed by "a box" raised about one line above the natural position
 % followed by "and more text" after a large space.
 Some text, and \myparbox[width = 50pt, height = 20pt, position = bottom, inner position = top]{a box} and more text.
 
 % Should look pretty much like normal text, with slight offsets down and over around the box.
 Some text, and \myparbox[width = 30pt]{a box} and more text.
 
 % The box should have very spread-out lines
 Some text, and
 \myparbox[width = 30pt, height = 100pt, inner position = stretch]
 {a box\par \vspace{\stretch{1}}with\par\vspace{\stretch{1}}words}
 and more text.
\end{document}
```

Using these techniques, you can (perhaps not easily at first) craft your own options and make them tweak the behavior of `\myparbox`.  For example, if you wanted to have a `color` option, you would link it to the argument of a `\textcolor` command.

Comment: Wow, that's a really nice, detailed and well-written answer!

Comment: @RyanReich Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: The same general approach (define keys, process as the content of an optional argument) applies to all possible keyval packages.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  Only the part about setting up keywords is somewhat `pgfkeys` specific.

Comment: For `[inner] position` you can also use the `.is choice` handler which is a little bit more flexible.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Not really, then I'd have to reproduce the `.get` code for each choice.

Comment: I think this is a very appropriate answer of mine to get the Guru badge.

Comment: Am I the only one that gets confused with the construction `position/.style = {positions/#1/.get = \myparboxPosition}`? I know how it works but it is hard to convince my mind that `.get` is actually setting `\myparboxPosition` and not the other way around...

Comment: We wanted to draw a line with ticks or other decorations on it
for a paper talking about musical structure. I decided to write a tikz macro with
some optional arguments in case it might become useful again, but also
to learn more about optional arguments in tikz. Iread the manual, and was ready to give up. Then I read this article. FWIW, it helped me write a little tikz macro to do what we wanted. The manual seems much clearer now :) https://gist.github.com/nickbailey/f2cb96cd07ac2a246ce4ead4f861c579

Answer (score 59):

Here is a short example of how to use keys by virtue of the [`keyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval).

The steps you need to follow are all based on the following macro:

```
\define@key{<family>}{<key>}{<function>}
```

1. Define your `<family>`: Use the above command by choosing some `<family>` name that all the keys will be associated with. In my example below, I chose the family name `myparbox`, since the keys should be associated with the macro `\myparbox`. They need not be the same as in my case.
2. Define your `<key>`s: You list all the keys that should be allowed for the `<family>`. In my example I defined the keys `fontcolor`, `color`, `width` and `align`, since these will have a meaning within my `\myparbox` command.
3. Define a `<function>` for each `<key>`: Whenever someone uses the `<key>=<value>`, `<function>` takes `<value>` as its argument `#1`. So, in the example below, I assign a macro for each one of the assigned values. This allows me to capture `<value>` so it can be used later. Note how the macro for each `<key>` is prefixed with `pb@` (short for `p`ar`b`ox`@`). This is because you may have a whole bunch of keys that you define, and you don't want the macros to clash with other packages, so the prefix makes each macro even more unique and further avoid clashes.

   As a more elaborate discussion on functions, consider the `color` key. The macro associated with the `color` key is defined as `\def\pb@color{#1}`. That is, whenever someone uses `color=<some color>`, it executes `\def\pb@color{<some color>}`, thereby assigning the color `<some color>` to the macro `\pb@color`.
4. Set your default values: This is done by using the `\setkeys{<family>}{<key>=<value> list}` command. In the example below, I listed the default key-value pairs as

   ```
   fontcolor=black
   color=white
   width=5cm
   align=t
   ```
5. Write your macro that uses the created `<key>`s: You macro has the following basic form:

   ```
   \newcommand{\<mymacro>}[2][]{%
     \setkeys{<family>}{#1}% Set the keys
     % do something with #2
   }
   ```

   This defines `\<mymacro>` with 2 arguments, the first of which is optional. That is, `\<mymacro>[<key>=<value> list]{<stuff>}`. At the first step, I assign whatever is passed as the optional argument `#1` to `\setkeys` under the same family name as my key set (`myparbox` in the example below). Secondly, I typeset `#2` using the macros defined by the keys.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\newlength{\pb@width}
\define@key{myparbox}{fontcolor}{\def\pb@fontcolor{#1}}
\define@key{myparbox}{color}{\def\pb@color{#1}}
\define@key{myparbox}{width}{\setlength\pb@width{#1}}
\define@key{myparbox}{align}{\def\pb@align{#1}}
% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{myparbox}{fontcolor=black,color=white,width=5cm,align=t}%
\newcommand{\myparbox}[2][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setkeys{myparbox}{#1}% Set new keys
  \colorbox{\pb@color}{\parbox[\pb@align]{\pb@width}{%
    \color{\pb@fontcolor}#2
  }}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myparbox{%
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
}

\myparbox[width=10cm]{%
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
}

\myparbox[width=7cm,fontcolor=red,color=blue]{%
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
}
\end{document}
```

The [`xkeyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) provides a similar, yet more advanced interface.

Comment: If I add another `\myparbox` call without any options after the last one in this example, the output is still formatted red on blue etc. Apparently, options persist between calls. One should probably define `\myparbox` so that it calls `\setkeys{myparbox}{<defaults>}` each time before executing `\setkeys{myparbox}{#1}`.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: Thanks for spotting this - I've used grouping to localize the setting of keys within `\myparbox`.

Comment: @Werner: Please is there any reason why you have `\begingroup` before `\setkeys`? I can't see the need for localization here.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: See @ MichaelPalmer's comment.

Comment: @Werner: I have seen it. That is why the *ltxkeys* package has `\...initializekeys` and `\...launchkeys`. Sometimes grouping can be costly. Anyway, the original `\setkeys` by the *keyval* package is rather cheap computationally.

Comment: Excellent and Simplest answer...!!!

Comment: Is it safe to use?  Can grouping affect the actual outputs? I have defined similar thing with similar grouping. I have deined more than 10 new commands with grouping as given here.

Comment: @user61681: Not sure what you mean by "safe to use". Can you provide an example of where it could be unsafe? See, for example, [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)

Answer (score 17):

The question is not explicitly about package writing, therefore I wonder, why until now noone mentioned `keycommand`, what was made to provide for document writers “an easy way to define commands or environments with optional keys” (cite from package manual), but this package could used inside of packages, as well. So, let me show this here.

Note, that there is a bug in this package, hence one has to add the patch provided by Joseph Wright in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794/) to the question [How do I use \ifcommandkey , or how do I check if a key was given?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35733/) *(as can also be supposed from the title of this question, the patch is strictly speaking only necessary, if one wants to utilise the `\ifcommandkey` command, but this will very often be the case)*:

```
\usepackage{keycommand}
% patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794/
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\/=8 %
  \@firstofone
    {
      \endgroup
      \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
      }
    }
%=======================%
```

Now with this package and using the simplified approach of Ryan Reich (giving the whole optional arguments) the definition of `\myparbox` will be

```
\newkeycommand{\myparbox}
  [enum vertalign={c,t,b}, boxheight=\height, enum innervertalign={c,t,b}, width][1]
  {%
  \parbox[\commandkey{vertalign}][\commandkey{boxheight}]
        [\commandkey{innervertalign}]{\commandkey{width}}{#1}%
  }
```

Here `enum …` is one of the two different choice types for key definition. *(BTW: in my humble opinion the package author mixed up the meaning of both, because with the `enum` type one has later **not** to give a number in the key, but with the `choice` key.)*
Note, that despite `width` is given as optional argument like all other keys, it is mandatory, because the underlying `\parbox` has a mandatory `width` argument. If the other three keys later are left out, the value given in definition is used, for keys from both `choice` types this is the first of the value list.

Adding definitions for colour keys and the conditional `\ifcommandkey{<key>}{<key> value not blank}{<key> value blank}` makes it more complex and more complicated:

```
\newkeycommand{\myparbox}
  [enum vertalign={c,t,b}, boxheight=\height, enum innervertalign={c,t,b},
  width, backgroundcolor, textcolor][1]
  {%
    \ifcommandkey{backgroundcolor}{\colorbox{\commandkey{backgroundcolor}}
      {\parbox[\commandkey{vertalign}][\commandkey{boxheight}]
            [\commandkey{innervertalign}]{\commandkey{width}}
            {\ifcommandkey{textcolor}{\color{\commandkey{textcolor}}}{}#1}%
    }}
    {\parbox[\commandkey{vertalign}][\commandkey{boxheight}]
            [\commandkey{innervertalign}]{\commandkey{width}}
            {\ifcommandkey{textcolor}{\color{\commandkey{textcolor}}}{}#1}%
    }%
  }
```

The hardest part is to get the brace pairs right and not to forget a brace.

All together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{keycommand}
% patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794/
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\/=8 %
  \@firstofone
    {
      \endgroup
      \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
      }
    }
%=======================%
\newkeycommand{\myparbox}
  [enum vertalign={c,t,b}, boxheight=\height, enum innervertalign={c,t,b},
  width, backgroundcolor, textcolor][1]
  {%
    \ifcommandkey{backgroundcolor}{\colorbox{\commandkey{backgroundcolor}}
      {\parbox[\commandkey{vertalign}][\commandkey{boxheight}]
            [\commandkey{innervertalign}]{\commandkey{width}}
            {\ifcommandkey{textcolor}{\color{\commandkey{textcolor}}}{}#1}%
    }}
    {\parbox[\commandkey{vertalign}][\commandkey{boxheight}]
            [\commandkey{innervertalign}]{\commandkey{width}}
            {\ifcommandkey{textcolor}{\color{\commandkey{textcolor}}}{}#1}%
    }%
  }
\begin{document}
X\myparbox[width=0.65em]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[width=0.65em, backgroundcolor=SkyBlue]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[vertalign=b, width=0.65em, backgroundcolor=SkyBlue]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[vertalign=b, boxheight=3\baselineskip, width=0.65em,
          backgroundcolor=SkyBlue]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[vertalign=b, innervertalign=b, boxheight=3\baselineskip,
          width=0.65em, backgroundcolor=SkyBlue]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[vertalign=t, innervertalign=b, boxheight=3\baselineskip,
          width=0.65em, backgroundcolor=SkyBlue,textcolor=Gold]{Z Z}X --
X\myparbox[vertalign=t, innervertalign=t, boxheight=3\baselineskip,
          width=0.65em, backgroundcolor=SkyBlue,textcolor=Gold]{Z Z}X
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of first example]

---

A feature not possible with `keyval`, but with newer, more advanced packages (e.g. `pgfkeys`), is the handling of not explicitly defined *(“unknown”)* keys. This is useful, when the command inside of new command definition itself already works with a key-value-approach. `keycommand` provides for these cases another optional argument, where an arbitrary key name has to be given (most useful something along “OtherKeys”/“OrigKeys”). Then all keys not known to the new key command are simply handed over to the underlying command.

See the following example, I needed to use the version, where an expansion delay is provided for commands in `|` pairs (defined in optional argument before new command name):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx,transparent}
\usepackage{keycommand}
% patch by Joseph Wright ("bug in the definition of \ifcommandkey (2010/04/27 v3.1415)"),
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35794/
\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \catcode`\/=8 %
  \@firstofone
    {
      \endgroup
      \renewcommand{\ifcommandkey}[1]{%
        \csname @\expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter
        \kcmd@nbk \commandkey {#1}//{first}{second}//oftwo\endcsname
      }
    }
%=======================%
\newkeycommand+[\|]{\transparentimage}[opacity][origkeys][1]
{%
  \begingroup
  \ifcommandkey{opacity}{|\transparent|{\commandkey{opacity}}}{}
    |\includegraphics|[\commandkey{origkeys}]{#1}
  \endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
\centering
\transparentimage{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\transparentimage[opacity=0.33]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\transparentimage[width=75pt]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\transparentimage[width=75pt,opacity=0.33]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\transparentimage[angle=45,width=106pt]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\transparentimage[angle=45,width=106pt,opacity=0.33]{example-grid-100x100pt.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Here the only new defined key is `opacity`, the keys `width` and `angle` are original keys from `\includegraphics`.

[image: screenshot of second example]

Answer (score 15):

Nowadays there is another package worth mentioning: `l3keys` (which is part of `expl3`). It is especially handy when using expl3 to define the low-level commands, but it is also handy otherwise. To define the command itself use `xparse`.

Code example (prototype, optional arguments of `\parbox` not functionally implemented):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { keyval }
    {
        width  .dim_set:N = \l__keyval_width_dim,
        height .dim_set:N = \l__keyval_height_dim,
        height .initial:n = { -1cm }, % dummy value for absence check
        color  .tl_set:N  = \l__keyval_color_tl,
        color  .initial:n = black       
    }
\cs_new:Npn \keyval_parbox:n #1
    {
        \parbox
            [][\dim_use:N \l__keyval_height_dim]
            { \dim_use:N \l__keyval_width_dim   }
            { \color { \l__keyval_color_tl } #1 }
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \myparbox } { O{} +m }
    {
        \group_begin:
        \keys_set:nn { keyval } { #1 }
        \keyval_parbox:n { #2 }
        \group_end:
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\myparbox[width=50mm,height=15pt,color=blue]{Quack}

\myparbox[width=50mm,height=2pt,color=red]{Quack}
\myparbox[width=50mm,color=yellow]{Quack}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14):

As noted at [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJY2y.png), `\setkeys` from the *keyval* package may not be nested. This is because it doesn't push any current state before commencing process. Besides this, we no longer have to repeatedly call `\define@key` to define several keys. Here is a *key command* approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltxkeys}
\makeatletter

% To avoid local groups when using \fbox parameters, the development version of
% ltxkeys package introduces the commands \ltxkeys@savefboxparam and 
% \ltxkeys@restorefboxparam.

% The commands \ltxkeys@initializekeys and \ltxkeys@launchkeys can be used to 
% re-initialize keys to their default values. This avoids creating local 
% groups when setting keys, but (by design) these commands will not re-initialize 
% 'option keys' (ie, keys that are package or class options). The ltxkeys 
% package deals with this via the hooks \ltxkeys@beforekeycmdsetkeys,
% \ltxkeys@beforekeycmdbody, \ltxkeys@afterkeycmdbody, and the commands
% \ltxkeys@savecmdkeyvalues and \ltxkeys@restorecmdkeyvalues, all of which apply
% to only key commands.
% 
\new@def*\ltxkeys@fboxparamstack{}
\robust@def*\ltxkeys@savefboxparam{%
  \xdef\ltxkeys@fboxparamstack{%
    \fboxrule=\the\fboxrule\relax\fboxsep=\the\fboxsep\relax
    \noexpand\@nil{\expandcsonce\ltxkeys@fboxparamstack}%
  }%
}
\robust@def*\ltxkeys@restorefboxparam{%
  \begingroup
  \def\x##1\@nil{\endgroup##1\gdef\ltxkeys@fboxparamstack}%
  \expandafter\x\ltxkeys@fboxparamstack
}
% \myparbox is defined as a robust command:
\ltxkeysrobust\ltxkeyscmd\myparbox[2][](%
  cmd/textcolor/black;
  cmd/framecolor/white;
  cmd/fillcolor/white;
  cmd/framerule/.4pt;
  cmd/framesep/3pt;
  cmd/width/5cm;
  cmd/align/t;
  bool/testbool/true;
){%
  \ltxkeys@savefboxparam
  \let\kval\keyval
  \fboxrule=\kval{framerule}\relax
  \fboxsep=\kval{framesep}\relax
  \fcolorbox{\kval{framecolor}}{\kval{fillcolor}}{%
    \parbox[\kval{align}]{\kval{width}}{%
      \color{\kval{textcolor}}%
      #2\ifkeyvalTF{testbool}{\texttt{\textcolor{black}{<<#1>>}}}{}%
    }%
  }%
  \ltxkeys@restorefboxparam
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newcommand*\sometext[1][1]{%
  \cptdotimes{#1}{%
    Here is some text that should fit in this paragraph box.
  }%
}

% No keys called here:
\myparbox{\sometext[3]}

\par\medskip
% Keys come last, if they are called:
\myparbox{\sometext[3]}
(width=10cm,framecolor=green,framerule=1pt,fillcolor=gray!15)

\par\medskip
\myparbox[Optional text]{\sometext[4]}
(width=7cm,framerule=4pt,framesep=20pt,textcolor=red,framecolor=brown,
fillcolor=yellow!25,testbool)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

## Using `expkv`

There are different ways on how to achieve this with `expkv` and related packages which I present in the following.

### Only `expkv`

The main package of `expkv` does only provide a very low level interface comparable to the widely known `keyval` package. You can define new keys with `\ekvdef` and there are no predefined handlers doing your job.

For instance to let a key store something in a macro you'd do

```
\ekvdef{set}{key}{\def\macro{#1}}
```

and to define an action for a key without a value you'd use

```
\ekvdefNoVal{set}{key}{action}
```

The following uses these two macros to define keys to get a `\mypbox` command.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage[]{color}

\makeatletter
\let\ifmypbox@frame\iffalse
\protected\def\mypbox@frametrue
  {\let\ifmypbox@frame\iftrue\let\mypbox@frame\fbox}
\protected\def\mypbox@framefalse
  {\let\ifmypbox@frame\iffalse\let\mypbox@frame\@firstofone}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{width}{\def\mypbox@wd{#1}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{height}{\def\mypbox@ht{#1}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{align}{\def\mypbox@pos{#1}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{content}{\def\mypbox@cpos{#1}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{color}{\def\mypbox@color{#1}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{frame sep}{\fboxsep=#1\relax}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{c}{\def\mypbox@pos{c}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{t}{\def\mypbox@pos{t}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{b}{\def\mypbox@pos{b}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{cc}{\def\mypbox@cpos{c}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{ct}{\def\mypbox@cpos{t}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{cb}{\def\mypbox@cpos{b}}
\protected\ekvdef{mypbox}{frame}{\mypbox@frametrue\def\mypbox@framecolor{#1}}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{frame}
  {\mypbox@frametrue\let\mypbox@framecolor\@empty}
\protected\ekvdefNoVal{mypbox}{no frame}
  {\mypbox@framefalse\let\mypbox@framecolor\@empty}
\newcommand*\mypbox@wd{\linewidth}
\newcommand*\mypbox@color{black}
\newcommand*\mypbox@ht{}
\newcommand*\mypbox@cpos{t}
\newcommand*\mypbox@pos{t}
\let\mypbox@frame\@firstofone

\ekvsetdef\mypbox@set{mypbox}

\newcommand*\mypbox[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \mypbox@set{#1}%
    \ifmypbox@frame
      \unless\ifx\mypbox@framecolor\@empty
        \expandafter\color\expandafter{\mypbox@framecolor}%
      \fi
    \fi
    \mypbox@frame
      {%
        \ifx\mypbox@ht\@empty
          \expandafter\@firstoftwo
        \else
          \expandafter\@secondoftwo
        \fi
        {\parbox[\mypbox@pos]}%
        {\parbox[\mypbox@pos][\mypbox@ht][\mypbox@cpos]}%
        {\mypbox@wd}
        {%
          \unless\ifx\mypbox@color\@empty
            \expandafter\color\expandafter{\mypbox@color}%
          \fi
          #2%
        }%
      }%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\mypbox{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=blue,frame sep=-\fboxrule]{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=red,width=5cm,height=3cm,cc,c]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame,height=1cm,b,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame=green,color=magenta,height=5mm,t,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\end{document}
```

---

### With `expkv-def`

The `expkv-def` package adds common key types and an interface to define such keys in a similar way to `pgfkeys` or `l3keys`. The following example defines the equivalent keys to the example above, but using the `expkv-def` syntax.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter
% a few internals
%% helpers for the frame options
\protected\def\mypbox@frametrue {\let\mypbox@frame\fbox}
\protected\def\mypbox@framefalse{\let\mypbox@frame\@firstofone}
%% helpers for the ht key
\newcommand*\mypbox@wht [1]{\parbox[\mypbox@pos][{#1}][\mypbox@cpos]}
\newcommand*\mypbox@woht   {\parbox[\mypbox@pos]}
\newsavebox\mypbox@box
% setting up the keys
\ekvdefinekeys{mypbox}
  {
     store   width     = \mypbox@wd
    ,initial width     = \linewidth
    ,data    height    = \mypbox@ht
    ,store   align     = \mypbox@pos
    ,initial align     = t
    ,store   content   = \mypbox@cpos
    ,initial content   = t
    ,dataT   color     = \mypbox@color
    ,noval   no color  = \let\mypbox@color\@gobble
    ,dimen   frame sep = \fboxsep
    ,code    frame     = \mypbox@frametrue\def\mypbox@framecolor{\color{#1}}
    ,noval   frame     = \mypbox@frametrue\let\mypbox@framecolor\@empty
    ,noval   no frame  = \mypbox@framefalse\let\mypbox@framecolor\@empty
    ,initial no frame
    ,nmeta   c         = align = c
    ,nmeta   t         = align = t
    ,nmeta   b         = align = b
    ,nmeta   cc        = content = c
    ,nmeta   ct        = content = t
    ,nmeta   cb        = content = b
  }
\protected\ekvsetdef\mypbox@set{mypbox}

\newcommand*\mypbox[2][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \mypbox@set{#1}%
      % store the parbox inside a box register so that the frame colour doesn't
      % affect the parbox contents.
      \sbox\mypbox@box
        {%
          \mypbox@ht\mypbox@wht\mypbox@woht
            {\mypbox@wd}%
            {\mypbox@color\color #2}%
        }%
      \mypbox@framecolor
      \mypbox@frame{\usebox\mypbox@box}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\mypbox{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=blue,frame sep=-\fboxrule]{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=red,width=5cm,height=3cm,cc,c]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame,height=1cm,b,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame=green,color=magenta,height=5mm,t,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\end{document}
```

---

### With `expkv-cs`

The `expkv-cs` package provides an interface to define a macro that takes a list of key=value pairs and handles it as separate arguments. This mechanism is fully expandable (but our example is not). The arguments will be passed on in the order the keys were specified.

Additionally there is a second mechanism, which forwards the key=value pairs as a formatted list from which specific keys can be called with helper macros. This variant will not be shown in this answer.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{expkv-cs}
\usepackage[]{color}

\makeatletter
\ekvcSplitAndForward\mypbox@split\mypbox@do
  {
     frame     = \relax
    ,align     = t
    ,height    = \relax
    ,content   = t
    ,width     = \linewidth
    ,color     = \relax
    ,frame sep = \fboxsep
  }
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\mypbox@split
  {
     default frame  = \@empty
    ,nmeta no frame = frame = \relax
    ,nmeta   c      = align = c
    ,nmeta   t      = align = t
    ,nmeta   b      = align = b
    ,nmeta   cc     = content = c
    ,nmeta   ct     = content = t
    ,nmeta   cb     = content = b
  }
\newcommand\mypbox@ifx[2]
  {%
    \ifx#1#2\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  }
\newcommand\mypbox[1][]
  {%
    \mypbox@split{#1}
  }
\newcommand\mypbox@do[8]
  {%
    % #1: frame
    % #2: align
    % #3: height
    % #4: content
    % #5: width
    % #6: color
    % #7: frame sep
    % #8: text
    \begingroup
      \mypbox@ifx\relax{#1}%
        {\@firstofone}
        {%
          \mypbox@ifx\@empty{#1}%
            {}
            {\color{#1}}%
          \fboxsep=#7\relax
          \fbox
        }%
      {%
        \mypbox@ifx\relax{#3}%
          {\parbox[#2]}
          {\parbox[#2][#3][#4]}%
        {#5}
        {%
          \mypbox@ifx\relax{#6}%
            {}%
            {\color{#6}}%
          #8%
        }%
      }%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\mypbox{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=blue,frame sep=-\fboxrule]{This is some text}

\noindent
\mypbox[frame=red,width=5cm,height=3cm,cc,c]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame,height=1cm,b,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\mypbox[frame=green,color=magenta,height=5mm,t,width=3cm]{This is some text}
\end{document}
```

---

The results of all three examples look the same:

[image]