# Can I use trig functions in TikZ within polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use simple mathematical functions such as sin, cos, and sqrt within the declaration of a TikZ coordinate.  I am finding that this works for cartesian coordinates, but breaks for polar coordinates:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:1/0.707) -- (0,0); % <-- works
% \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:{1/cos(45)}) -- (0,0); % <--doesn't work
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,{1/tan(45)}) -- (0,0); % <--works
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is this just a known limitation, or is there some way to get around this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is actually a bug that is fixed in the CVS version of PGF/TikZ, see [Using math in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/using-math-in-tikz)

As percusse reports in his answer to that question, you can get around this bug by simply adding a space after the closing brace in the radius calculation:

```
\draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:{1/cos(45)} ) -- (0,0);
```

cjorssen also posted the fix that is now in the CVS version, and which you can use in your document. See [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41931/586) to said question.

---

### Original answer

You can get around this by using the `let` keyword to do the calculation outside the coordinate. This is described in section **14.15 The Let Operation** of the manual, which is on page 150 (for version 2.10, dated 25 October 2010).

I used `cycle` to close the path, as this ensures a proper merging of the lines at that corner.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \n1 = {1/cos(45)}  in
   (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:\n1) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So it is just a known limitation then?  If my path has 20 coordinates in it, I will need to define a let variable for each one of them?  I was hoping that I could pull it off with an extra set of braces.

Comment: @nispio Seems so, though I'm hardly an expert.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up research and subsequent edit!  It is much more satisfying to hear that the problem is the result of a bug, rather than an oversight in the implementation of features. However, the workaround definitely makes the code more fragile, since removing a seemingly innocuous space could break it.

Answer (score 5):

I personally prefer to do the calculations separately via `\pgfmathsetmacro` and then use the result.  Otherwise using an additional `{}` group is necessary for the parser to to work.

### References:

- [Using math in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/using-math-in-tikz)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\CosValue}{1/cos(45)}%
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:\CosValue) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\CosValue}{cos(45)}%
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (45:1/\CosValue) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was originally using `\pgfmathsetmacro` but the number of them was starting to pile high because I had many coordinates within the path.  Can you comment on what you mean by an additional `{}` group being necessary?  I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Well, I was originally referring to the `{1/tan(45)}` which you already figured out, but looking more closely now I see that does not quite work with polar coordinate. I thought there was an question here (with an answer from 
Andrew Stacey?) addressing this parsing issue, but can't seem to locate it.

Comment: Thanks, your comment made me do a little search, which led me to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/using-math-in-tikz

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Have added that to the answer...  Your search skills are better than mine. Since I had incorrectly assumed who answered it, that did not make my search very likely to succeed.

Comment: It can sometimes be easier to find stuff with Google, rather than the site search. I searched for *tex.stackexchange polar coordinate tikz calculations* and it was one of the first hits.