# Error caused by TikZ/PGF trigonometric functions

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I'm a bit confused about a failure I'm seeing with an inline `\cos` call.  In the code below there I perform contortions with `\let`, `\pgfmathparse`, and `\pgfmathresult`  However, the commented line should, in my understanding, do the exact same thing.  Instead it fails with an error.  I seem to be missing something and I still don't have a good handle on doing math with pgf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{155}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_main_coords]
\tikzstyle{grid}=[thin,color=red]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (1,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (-1,0,0);
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,1) node[anchor=south]{$z$};

\foreach \a in {0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90}{
    \pgfmathparse{cos(\a)};
    \let\c=\pgfmathresult;
    \tdplotdrawarc[grid]{(0,0,{sin(\a)})}{\c}{0}{180}{}{};
     % When this line is uncommented it fails.
%   \tdplotdrawarc[grid]{(0,0,{sin(\a)})}{{cos(\a)}}{0}{180}{}{};
}

\foreach \rot in {-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90} {
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\rot}{90}{0};
    \tdplotdrawarc[grid,tdplot_rotated_coords]{(0,0,0)}{1}{90}{180}{}{};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works with the current CVS version of TikZ, so I suspect: [Using math in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41828)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Qrrbrbirlbel, it's due to a bug, which has already been discussed on the site; [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99519/can-i-use-trig-functions-within-polar-coordinates), for instance. That bug should be fixed in the next official TikZ release.

If you have an up-to-date, non-CVS version of TikZ, you will make the error disappear by inserting two spaces in the problematic line, like so:

`\tdplotdrawarc[grid]{(0,0,{sin(\a)} )}{{cos(\a)} }{0}{180}{}{};`

[image]