# Error with TIkz function and polar coordinates in Texlive/MacTex

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive, polarplot

I am encountering a rather odd `typesetting` error with `Tikz` when running the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,calc,fadings,decorations}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=2em,y=2em]
    \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:{sin(90)});
\end{tikzpicture}\]

\end{document}
```

The above runs fine with `MikTex` (Windows) but gives this error when run in `TexLive (Ubuntu)` or `MacTex`:

```
Package `tikz` Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a `semicolon`? \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0:{sin(90)})
```

If I change (0:{sin(90)}) to (0,{sin(90)}) or (0:{1}) then it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example works fine here, with TeX Live 2013. Do you have the same version of PGF/TikZ everywhere?

Comment: Thanks  @TorbjørnT. I should have looked up on this site (I did, but found nothing). It was already covered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99519/can-i-use-trig-functions-within-polar-coordinates). 

Now I need to find a way to update my PGF/TikZ, and also to close my question.

Comment: I voted to close your question with the link you provided.