# what is the correct syntax for using let in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking at this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99519/can-i-use-trig-functions-within-polar-coordinates)  But still can't get the syntax right.

I have this example to draw a line of length 2 units, which works fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw  (0,0) -- ({2*cos(30)},{2*sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the length a variable. So I wrote (following the answer in the link above)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \r1={2} in 
        (0,0) -- ({\r1*cos(30)},{\r1*sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this gives syntax error

```
    Package tikz Error: ``\p'' or ``\n'' expected. \draw let \r
```

I thought maybe the `{` is confusing it. So I changed it to

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \r1={2} in (0,0) -- (\r1*{cos(30)},\r1*{sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Still an error. I kept trying different things, and they all are failing. So I gave up. I know I need to have {} in tickz when doing calculations. So I do not understand the problem.

Any help on the correct syntax?

**Update**

I also tried `p1` but it gives this error

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \p1={2} in (0,0) -- ({\p1*cos(30)},{\p1*sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

 Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \draw let \p1={2}
```

Then I tried removing the `{}`

```
 \draw let \p1={2} in (0,0) -- (\p1*cos(30),\p1*sin(30));
```

An error.  I tried keeping the `{}` around the trig only

```
  \draw let \p1={2} in (0,0) -- (\p1*{cos(30)},\p1*{sin(30)});
```

error. I also tried

```
   \draw let \p1={2} in (0,0) -- ({\p1}*{cos(30)},{\p1}*{sin(30)});
```

error.

Tikz syntax is mystery to me.

Comment: `r` is not a recognized type, you are not defining a custom macro. You can only use `p`oints or `n`umbers.

Comment: @percusse I actualy tried `p1` also (this was in the number of other trials I mentioned, I just did not show it. Will update now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2` is a number, thus the `let` assignment would be `\n1` or `\n{r1}` if the variable is named `1` or `r1`. `\p` expects a point, e.g., `\p{1} = (3, 4)`. `\x1` and `\y1` then selects the *x* and *y* components of point `\p1`. `\r` is not defined.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw let \n1={2} in
        (0,0) -- ({\n1*cos(30)},{\n1*sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With the new `math` library, `\r1` can be defined as array variable `\r`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[evaluate={
  \r1=2;
}]
  (0,0) -- ({\r1*cos(30)},{\r1*sin(30)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. So I should have used `n1` if the RHS is number. Ok, will remember this. I think I will use `evaluate` it seems better.

Answer (score 3):

There is a confusion I think about the function of let instead of the syntax I think.

The main idea of `let` syntax (and `calc` library in general) is not about doing arbitrary computations or numerical assignments. There is `pgfmath` for that and the associated macros.

`let` provides a nice frontend for graphical computations such as defining points and finding their `x,y` coordinates etc.

Hence it only understands two things, numbers and points and it understands them by the starting letter `p` or `n`. If it stumbles upon a `p` it starts to parse the point definition just as it would be doing it on the path and also defines two additional macros `x` and `y`.

For example, you can say things like

`\p1=($(a)-(b)$), \p{aaaa} = (a|-b)`

then it already gives you automatically, `\x1,\y1` as the first point coordinates and `\x{aaaa},\y{aaaa}` as the second point coordinates such that you can use it in number crunching.

`\n` macros are numbers and they are parsed with `\pgfmath` engine and again can be used later together with others.

Here the problem is that `r` doesn't exist hence the error is correct and also `2` is not a point so cannot be a proper syntax for `\p1`.