# TikZ: Draw rectangular triangle by raising a perpendicular on the hypotenuse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am given the points A, B and X within a `tikzpicture` environment, like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (3.6,0);
  \coordinate (X) at (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I would like to construct the coordinate C as in this picture: [image: Triangle]

Using circle and straightedge, I would raise a perpendicular on AB in X and intersect it with the circle having AB as a diameter.
I'm sure there is a clean way to do this in TikZ (without doing any coordinate calculations by hand). However browsing through the (substantial) documentation, I wasn't able to find a direct answer.

For portability, I would like to have a solution in plain TikZ (without the `tkz-euclide` package).

**EDIT**

For clarification: By a "clean way" I'm trying to express that I want to tell TikZ "what I mean". So for example: Introducing the midpoint O of the line segment [AB] would be ok, as well as saying that the distance of C and O should be the same as the distance of A and O. But direct computations of the coordinates, for example based on the [Geometric mean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem) or trigonometric functions should be avoided.

As a fast check: If there is some function like `sqrt` or `atan` etc. in your code, then it's probabily not what I'm looking for. Also, your code should still work if I alter the starting coordinates of A, B and X (they should still be on a common line, though, but this line might not be horizontal any more.)

Comment: Probably easier to use polar coordinates and take X as the origin?

Comment: @cfr: I don't think so: Note that X is not the center of the circle. It's just some arbitary point on the line segment AB.

Comment: Sorry. Yes. Not X. But if it is within a circle, it seems to make sense to set the coordinates in polar with the center at the origin? But you can otherwise use the `intersections` library to get the intersection of the arc and a line from X upwards. I'm not sure why you'd do this this way, but you can.

Comment: Did you see **Section 2.16 Intersecting Paths** on tikz the user guide?

Comment: Or **4.2.2 Intersecting a Line and a Circle**.

Comment: @Sigur: I've played around a bit with the intersection, but it felt cumbersome and the (invisible) helper paths unnecessarily increased the borders of my tikzpicture. I hope for a solution using coordinate computations only (maybe by introducing an auxiliary point like the center of the circle).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here a solution with `intersections`. The borders of the image are fixed with a `clip`. I am still searching for a solution without the helper lines, and let you know when i found it.

At the moment you have to use the `clip` and adjust it manually.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, through}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (3.6,0);
    \coordinate (x) at (2,0);

    \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-.01) rectangle (3.6,1.8);
      \path [name path=px] (x) -- ++(90:2cm);
      \node at ($(a)!.5!(b)$) [name path=pc, circle through={(a)}] {};
      \draw [name intersections={of=px and pc}] (a) -- (intersection-1) -- (b) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Here another piece of code using the `let` command in combination with `intersections`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=6mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate [label={180:$A$}] (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate [label={0:$B$}] (b) at (3.6,0);
    \coordinate [label={-90:$X$}] (x) at (2,0);

    \draw [dashed] let \p1 = ($(b)-(a)$) in [name path=pa] (a) arc (180:0:\x1/2);
    \draw [dashed] let \p1 = ($(b)-(a)$) in [name path=px] (x) |- ($(x)+(90:\x1/2)$);
    \draw [name intersections={of=pa and px}] (a) -- (intersection-1) node [label={90:$C$}] {} -- (b) -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

**Update:**

As requested some more information:

> *`let` Command*

With the `let` command you can use a *point register* (`\p[n]`) or *number register* (`\n[n]`) for drawing your path. I used the calculation of a point (`\p1`) by path-calculations fo existing points and reuse the `x` and `y` coordinates (`\x1`, `\y1`) in the drawing part of the command (after `in`).

The `let` command is also described under `14.15` (p. 161) of the [pgfmanual 3.0](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

> *Coordinate* `(c)`

Adjust the last `\draw` command like this to add a `coordinate` at the intersection point `(intersection-1)` called `(c)`. This way you get your coordinate and can access it later in your code by calling it.

```
\draw [name intersections={of=pa and px}] (a) -- (intersection-1) coordinate (c) node [label={90:$C$}] {} -- (b) -- cycle;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the manual clipping isn't that great. Would it be possible to restrict the circle to the upper half circle? After that (and with the px path short enough), the automatic clipping should be fine I guess.

Comment: I got many answers and I'm figuring which one I should accept. Your update comes quite close to what I was hoping for. However, at the moment the constructed coordinate has the name (intersection-1) and not (C). I have to confess that I don't understand the `let ...` parts of your code. Would you mind explaining a little bit what's going on there? And could you rename the coordinate into (C)? Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

Another alternative with `calc` frenzy

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=180:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=0:$B$] (B) at (3.6,0);
  \coordinate[label=270:$X$] (X) at (0.5,0);
  \coordinate (O) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
  \draw (A) let \p1=($(B)-(A)$),\p2=($(O)-(X)$),\n1={acos(2*\x2/\x1)} in 
       arc (180:0:0.5*\x1) ($(O)!1!-\n1:(A)$) 
       coordinate[label=90:$C$] (C) --(X);
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. I tried it, and it works. However, I have no idea what the line `\draw (A) let \p1...` does. Would you mind explaining that line a little bit?

Comment: @azimut Here is some http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247315/3235

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution with intersections like moospit's answer, but this one uses an arc (half a circle) to compute the intersection, and it only uses the intersections library.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x/\l in {0/A, 2/X, 3.6/B}{
  \coordinate (\l) at (\x,0);
  \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum size=1pt, label=270:\l] at (\x,0) {};
}
\path[name path=xpath] (X) --++ (0,2);
\draw[line width=.3pt, gray, name path=arc] (A) arc (180:0:1.8);

\path[name intersections={of=xpath and arc, by=C}];
\node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum size=1pt, label=90:C] at (C) {};

\draw (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (X) -- (C);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also... **Animation time!**

[image: figure 2]

Comment: how you get the animation?

Answer (score 7):

Althogh the OP required a solution without using [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide), I think this might be useful for somebody else:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Initial points A,B, X, O
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){X}
\tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){O}
% The arc
\tkzDrawArc[dashed,color=gray!60,thin](O,B)(A)
% Finding C
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through X](A,X){O}
\tkzInterLC[R](X,tkzPointResult)(O,4cm)
\tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
% Drawing lines
\tkzDrawSegments(X,C A,B A,C C,B)
% Adding labels
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,X,O,C)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,X,O)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Even though the question specified no `tkz-euclide` ;).

Comment: @cfr. True. I didn't notice it. Initially I thought about deleting the answer, then I decided to keep it adding a remark.

Comment: Well, it is a useful answer if somebody else doesn't have the OP's restrictions. So I don't see why you should delete it. People answer tikz questions with pstricks solutions and vice-versa for that kind of reason all the time.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: Warning removed. If both [Euclid and egreg say it is true](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255153/tikz-draw-rectangular-triangle-by-raising-a-perpendicular-on-the-hypotenuse#comment610375_255176), it must be true.

---

Here's a solution which requires no additional libraries.

My solution uses the fact that AB is a diameter of the circle and that C is a point on the circumference of that circle. This means that angle CAB is equal to angle BCX since ACB is a right-angle. So tan CAB is CX/AX and tan BCX is (AB-AX)/CX. Hence CX/AX = (AB-AX)/CX.  Since AB and AX are known, we can solve for CX = root of AX(AB-AX).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [circle radius/.store in=\myradius, circle radius=1.8, my length/.store in=\myl, my length=2]
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (2*\myradius,0);
  \coordinate (X) at (\myl,0);
  \coordinate (C) at (\myl,{sqrt(\myl*(2*\myradius - \myl))});
  \draw [densely dashed, gray] (A) arc (180:0:\myradius);
  \draw (A) node [left] {$A$} -- (B) node [right] {$B$} -- (C) node [above] {$C$} edge node [below, pos=1] {$X$} (X) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: dropped vertical]

Comment: By what we call Euclid's second theorem (not sure it's international), CX² = AX · BX.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean_theorem the name is **right triangle altitude theorem** or **geometric mean theorem**. Actually, this is the kind of solution which I wanted to exclude by "without doing any coordinate calculations by hand".

Comment: @azimut I don't really understand what would count, in that case, as an acceptable solution. percusse's solution doesn't count as doing calculations by hand but this does? That solution is great, but I don't see that it avoids doing the calculations any more than mine does. Indeed, you said in comments `I hope for a solution using coordinate computations only...`. So you want to do it with coordinate *computations* rather than *calculations*? What is the difference exactly?

Comment: @azimut I think the name varies. See [egreg's comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255153/tikz-draw-rectangular-triangle-by-raising-a-perpendicular-on-the-hypotenuse/255176#comment610375_255176) above.

Comment: @cfr: I've added an attept for an explanation the question.

Comment: @azimut Then it seems to me you really need something like the `intersections` library because you need something to do the computations behind the scenes. You could set up a solution like mine as a `pic` which you could then use without including the computations. But you'd still need the code to do the calculations somewhere whether in the preamble, in a library you load or whatever. *Something* has to tell the programme some stuff about Euclid because I think it missed out on egreg's course on the Elements!

Comment: @cfr: Right. I had the hope that the `calc` library would also do the job, since there are some nice commands which feel quite close.

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, my first test with [rulercompass](http://ctan.org/pkg/rulercompass). You don't need any coordinate calculation by hand, only some knowledge of technical drawing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}[stop jumping, max size={\textwidth}{\textheight}, ruler compass/ruler length=5cm]
% Three original points
\path (0,0) node[name=A, ruler compass/point=red, label={A}];
\path (3.6,0) node[name=B, ruler compass/point=red, label={B}];
\path (2,0) node[name=X, ruler compass/point=red, label={X}];
\pause
% Line through A and B
\ruler<+->{A}{B}
% We need center of A-B segment, so we draw two circles
\compass<+->{A}{B}
\compass<+->{B}{A}
% and the line through circles intersections give us A-B midpoint
\point<.->{cAB}{cBA}{1} % point a
\point<.->{cAB}{cBA}{2} % point b
\ruler<+->{a}{b}
\point<.->{rAB}{rab}{1} % point c
% We can draw a circle through A and B
\compass<+->{c}{A}
% Now we need a perpendicular through X
\compass<+->{X}{c}
\point<.->{cXc}{rAB}{1} % point d
\compass<+->{c}{d}
\compass<+->{d}{c}
\point<.->{ccd}{cdc}{1} % point e
\point<.->{ccd}{cdc}{2} % point f
% We got it!
\ruler<+->{e}{f}
% Intersection between perpendicular thorugh X and circle thorugh A-B
\point<.->{ref}{ccA}{1} % point g
% We can draw the final triangle
\draw<+->[thick,red] (A)--(B)--(g)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

tan CBX = tan ACX then CX^2 = AX*BX : graphic illustration of the geometric mean.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A) at (-2,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1.6,0);
\coordinate (X) at (0,0);

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Yc}{sqrt(2*1.6)}

\coordinate (C) at (0,\Yc);

\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle (X)--(C);

\foreach \Coor/\Text/\Pos in 
    {A/$A$/below,
    B/$B$/below,
    X/$X$/below,
    C/$C$/above%
    }
    \node[label={[label distance=-2pt]\Pos:\Text}] at (\Coor) {} ;

\node[label=below:$a\vphantom{b}$] at ($(A)!.5!(X)$) {} ;
\node[label=below:$b$] at ($(B)!.5!(X)$) {} ;
\node[label={[label distance=-2pt]left:$\sqrt{ab}$}] at ($(C)!.5!(X)$) {} ;

\draw
pic[draw=orange,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=.5cm] {angle=C--B--X}
pic[draw=orange,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=.5cm] {angle=A--C--X} ;

\draw[dashed] let   \p1=(C),
                    \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
    (B) arc (0:180:\n1) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this what I said? Though it is a nice diagram to illustrate the method.

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry for making a double.

Answer (score 4):

An example showing how it can be done with MetaPost, for whom it may interest. It uses the `intersectionpoint` instruction, which searches and gives the first intersection point between two given paths (when it exists, of course) as its names points out. So the core instruction here are:

```
perp = X -- (X+(B-A)) rotatedaround(X, 90);
```

which creates a perpendicular to (AB) starting from X, of sufficient length (it must intersect the half circle), and

```
C = perp intersectionpoint halfcirc;
```

which is pretty self-explanatory.

Included in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience (many LaTeX users don't know how to run MetaPost).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    pair A, B, C, X; path halfcirc, perp;
    A = origin; B = (3.6cm, 0); X = (2cm, 0);
    halfcirc = halfcircle zscaled (B-A) shifted (.5[A,B]);
    perp = X -- (X+(B-A)) rotatedaround(X, 90);
    C = perp intersectionpoint halfcirc;
    beginfig(0);
      draw halfcirc dashed evenly;
      draw X--C; draw A--B--C--cycle;
      forsuffixes M = A, B, X: label.bot("$" & str M & "$", M); endfor;
      label.top("$C$", C);
    endfig;
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]