# How can I smooth out the corners of a pgfplots plot

Tags: pgfplots

How do I smooth out the corners in the following graph?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
  x=.75cm,
  y=.75cm,    
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [line width=2pt,mark=none,domain=-5:-2] {3};
\addplot [line width=2pt,mark=none,domain=-2:-1] { 2*x^2-5};
\addplot [line width=2pt,mark=none,domain=-1:1]  {-3};
\addplot [line width=2pt,mark=none,domain=1:2]   {2*x^2-5};
\addplot [line width=2pt,mark=none,domain=2:5]   {3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it cheating to use a piecewise defined function?

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{MyFunction}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{%
        (and(   1,    #1<-2)*(3)          +%
        (and(#1>=-2,  #1< -1)*(2*#1^2 - 5)+%
        (and(#1>= -1,  #1< 1)*(-3)        +%
        (and(#1>= 1,  #1< 2)*(2*#1^2 - 5) +%
        (and(#1>= 2,    1  )*(3)%
    }%
}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    axis x line=center,
    axis y line=center,
    xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    xlabel style={below right},
    ylabel style={above left},
    xmin=-5.5, xmax=5.5,
    ymin=-5.5, ymax=5.5,
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain=-5:5, blue, samples=100, ultra thick] {MyFunction(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

See [What is the clearest way to graph a piecewise function?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/what-is-the-clearest-way-to-graph-a-piecewise-function) and the links within for reference.

Comment: Not cheating at all.  I'm curious though.... you omitted my rescale of the `x` and `y` units and the font size.  Perhaps you just chose to omit these, but since you reworked my MWE very nicely I'm wondering whether there's a deeper significance to this.

Comment: @A.Ellett not really any significance, just personal preference - I like my tick labels to inherit the fontsize of the other parts of the document, but again, just personal preference :) For a `standalone` document, the `x` and `y` units don't seem relevant

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the syntax pgfmath syntax.  It looks like there are unbalanced parentheses.  Could you explain what's happening there?  Or, point me to the correct place in the documentation?

Comment: @A.Ellett It seems the bug is not still fully fixed. See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41828/using-math-in-tikz

Answer (score 12):

An alternative is use of  `line cap=round` in the `addplot[option]`

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  every axis/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
  x=.75cm,
  y=.75cm,    
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [line width=2pt,line cap=round,mark=none,domain=-5:-2] {3};
\addplot [line width=2pt,line cap=round,mark=none,domain=-2:-1] { 2*x^2-5};
\addplot [line width=2pt,line cap=round,mark=none,domain=-1:1]  {-3};
\addplot [line width=2pt,line cap=round,mark=none,domain=1:2]   {2*x^2-5};
\addplot [line width=2pt,line cap=round,mark=none,domain=2:5]   {3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```