# Allowing first undelimited argument to be empty

Tags: macros, tex-core, delimiters

Consider the following macro definitions:

```
\def\mymacro#1{\mymacroii#1\nil}
\def\mymacroii#1#2\nil{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    empty%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}%
\mymacro{foo}% -> f
\mymacro{}
\bye
```

This is supposed to extract the first character of the parameter to `\mymacro`. This works, but only if the argument is not empty.

How must I change my macros, so that the call `\mymacro{}` works as expected, i.e. outputs "empty"? Note, that is is only a simplified version. In reality I have several checks in `\mymacroii` for the first character, if it is a number, an opening brace, and so on.

This question is for sure related to [Why does TeX remove braces around delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39882/33933), but I couldn't apply those informations to my case.

Comment: Have you looked at the various token tests in `expl3` (we have tests for opening brace, ... plus a very robust 'first token' function)?

Comment: @JosephWright No, I haven't. This code is supposed to be used in my `pst-optexp` package, which doesn't use `expl3`. I don't want to add that dependencies for now, especially because I haven't worked with it at all.

Comment: I meant 'you could see how we've tackled this and use the same ideas': ther has been lots of testing of a number of approaches to these 'low level' problems.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for the suggestion. I started from some ideas in the `pstricks` package. I had a look at the `expl3` files, but couldn't get a good starting point. Where could I start for investigating on these specific tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\def\mymacro#1{\mymacroii#1{empty}\nil}
\def\mymacroii#1#2\nil{%
    #1%
}%

\mymacro{foo}% -> f

\mymacro{}
\bye
```

In your version, in the empty case, the inner call is

```
\mymacroii\nil
```

so `#1` is `\nil` and then it starts looking for the next `\nil` (which isn't there) to make `#2` and things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, my example was too minimal. In reality I have several different checks for the first argument in `\mymacroii`, it `#1` is a number, a `(`, a `<` etc. I added this information to my question.

Comment: @Christoph Can't you just do your tests sequentially?

Comment: @Christoph well you can add those to mine, the point is structuring that way means that #1 in your actual macro is never empty so you can write the tests knowing there is something there.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, it seems to work now. I'll test this solution in my package, before accepting the answer and closing the question.

Answer (score 3):

Just check for emptyness first.

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
\def\mymacro#1{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \expandafter\firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\secondoftwo
  \fi
  {empty}%
  {\mymacroii#1\nil}%
}
\def\mymacroii#1#2\nil{#1}
```

Just to get the flavor with LaTeX3, here's a version that allows you to define a function that examines the first token of the argument provided it was not empty in the first place (in this case it would output `empty`). It works also in expanded definitions, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\mymacro}{ m }
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
   { empty }
   { \christoph_examine_first:f { \tl_head:n { #1 } } }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \christoph_examine_first:n #1
 {
  Whatever~you~want~with~#1~which~is~one~token
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \christoph_examine_first:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\mymacro{foo}

\mymacro{}

\edef\x{\mymacro{foo}\mymacro{}}\x

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I used David's answer, which fits better to the rest of my code.