# Square brackets in listings caption

Tags: listings, captions

How to add square brackets as a caption in a listing? I tried putting caption inside of "{}", but then the output is quiet weird.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Algorithm [1] - example}]
    example
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Potential duplicate: [ ] inside an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99495)  In any event, the rules for nested square brackets are explained there.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Don't think it's a duplicate of that one. Note that the problem still occur when the user wrap in a single brace group (some internal interference of packages make it so that 4 levels of nested brace groups is required to avoid the issue, or alternatively make it "unbreakable" (with [TeX automatically remove brace groups](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39882/why-does-tex-remove-braces-around-delimited-arguments)) e.g. `{{Algorithm [1] - example}\relax}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Algorithm \unexpanded{[1]} - example}]
```

works on me. or as Manuel said:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Algorithm {[1]} - example}]
```

Comment: Just `{[1]}` is enough.

Comment: @Manuel I misunderstood, what he said. I thought, he meant, that this doesnt work.

Comment: @Ivan You might have seen, that Latex used the `[1]` somehow. To prevent Latex from using stuff `\noexpand or \unexpanded` can help. If you have no output, it is one expansion to less or at the wrong point. But this happens only in rare cases. Apparently, in this case `{ }` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the way in which the `\lstKV@OptArg`-mechanism of the listings-package is defined:

Using listings 2020/03/24 Version 1.8d, the MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Algorithm [1] - example}]
    example
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

yields the following output:

[image]

The caption-key is defined as follows:

```
3373 \lst@Key{caption}\relax{\lstKV@OptArg[{#1}]{#1}%
3374     {\def\lst@caption{##2}\def\lst@@caption{##1}}%
3375     \let\lst@title\@empty}
```

The `\lstKV@OptArg`-mechanism in turn is defined as follows:

```
431 \def\lstKV@OptArg[#1]#2#3{%
432     \gdef\@gtempa[##1]##2{#3}\lstKV@OptArg@{#1}#2\@}
433 \def\lstKV@OptArg@#1{\@ifnextchar[\lstKV@OptArg@@{\lstKV@OptArg@@[#1]}}
434 \def\lstKV@OptArg@@[#1]#2\@{\@gtempa[#1]{#2}}
```

Both `\lstKV@OptArg@` and `\lstKV@OptArg@@` pass arguments to other macros as `]`-delimited arguments without taking into account the case of these arguments as well containing that delimiter, which at the time of carrying out these other macros yields erroneous matching-up of argument-delimiters.

If this is taken into account by having `\lstKV@OptArg@` and `\lstKV@OptArg@@` pass `]`-delimited arguments nested between `{..}`, like in the example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\def\lstKV@OptArg@#1{\@ifnextchar[\lstKV@OptArg@@{\lstKV@OptArg@@[{#1}]}}%
\def\lstKV@OptArg@@[#1]#2\@{\@gtempa[{#1}]{#2}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Algorithm [1] - example}]
    example
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

, then you get:

[image]