# How to write a macro that is braces sensitive?

Tags: macros, plain-tex, braces

In the `xparse` package, there is the `g` type of argument which captures things inside a pair of TeX group tokens. This makes it possible to define commands `\foo` that behaves differently for `\foo{a}` and `\foo a`. I am interested in whether such type of macro is possible in plain TeX (I guess yes) and if it is possible, how can it be implemented. I am new to plain TeX and I appreciate detailed explanation of  the workflow of such a macro. I would also be happy to learn about other possibilities such as in e-TeX instead of plain TeX.

#### Edit

Only after reading the answers did I realize that it was impossible at first look because all I was thinking was `\def\foo#1...` (and indeed it is impossible if this form is used).

Comment: It's possible, but it's bad syntax. Under normal TeX conventions, `\foo a` and `\foo{a}` should be considered equivalent (when the argument consists of a single  token as in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I know it's bad syntax otherwise `xparse` would not declare it as obsolete, but it is (extensively) used in e.g. `physics` package. I am just not sure about whether it can be done in plain, or it requires some features of the engine.

Comment: It's indeed used in `physics`. My opinion about the package is that it has good ideas, but I can't recommend its usage. The weird syntax is just one among the several reasons for not recommending it.

Comment: Due to the weird syntax I end up adding `\relax` here and there ... but I guess I will still use it.

Comment: See also: [macros - How to make commands with mandatory braces? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/618693/how-to-make-commands-with-mandatory-braces) For delimited arguments see [macros - Why does TeX remove braces around delimited arguments? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39882/why-does-tex-remove-braces-around-delimited-arguments)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\futurelet`

```
\let\leftbracechar={
\def\foo{%
  \begingroup
  \futurelet\footemp\innerfoo
}%
\def\innerfoo{%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \ifx\footemp\leftbracechar
  \expandafter\fooatleftbrace
  \else
  \expandafter\fooatnoleftbrace
  \fi
}%
\def\fooatleftbrace#1{Argument in braces is: {\bf #1}}
\def\fooatnoleftbrace#1{Argument without braces is: {\bf #1}}


\foo a

\foo{a}

\bye
```

[image]

, but be aware that this can be confused by implicit characters, i.e., by things like `\foo\bgroup huh?...`

Besides this, the check is only about tokens (be they explicit or implicit character tokens) where the category code is 1 (begin group) and the character code equals the character code of the curly-opening-brace-character. The check does not work out with character tokens where the category code is 1 (begin group) but the character code is different.

But you can implement a full expandable check which tells you whether the first token **inside** a macro argument is an explicit character token of category code 1 (begin group) no matter what its character code might be:

```
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UDCheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked has leading
%%                       catcode-1-token>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked has no leading
%%                       catcode-1-token>}%
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherBrace#1{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{{}Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{{Test}}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\leavevmode\hrulefill\null

% Now let's have some fun: Give [ the same functionality as {:
\catcode`\[=\the\catcode`\{

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{[}Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{[Test}}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\leavevmode\hrulefill\null

% Now let's see that the test on explicit characters is not fooled by implicit characters:
\let\bgroup={

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{\bgroup\egroup Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{\bgroup Test\egroup}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\leavevmode\hrulefill\null    

% The test is also not fooled by implicit active characters:
\catcode`\X=13
\let X={

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{X\egroup Test}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%

\UDCheckWhetherBrace{X Test\egroup}%
                    {The first token of the arg is an explicit catcode 1 char.}%
                    {The first token of the arg is not an explicit catcode 1 char.}%


\bye
```

[image]

---

In order to see how `\UDCheckWhetherBrace` works, let's write it with different line-breaking and different indentation:

The gist is: Have the argument's first token hit by `\string` and use TeX's catching of brace-balanced arguments for finding out whether an opening brace or something else was neutralized/was turned into a catcode-12-sequence:

```
\long\def\UDCheckWhetherBrace#1{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter
  \secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
  \expandafter{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
  \expandafter{%
  \string#1.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
             %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
  \expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
              %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
  {\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
}%
```

For example

```
\UDCheckWhetherBrace{test}{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields:

```
\romannumeral0%
\expandafter
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
\expandafter{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
\expandafter{%
\string test.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
              %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
\expandafter{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
\expandafter{%
\string test.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
              %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out the `\expandafter`-chain and `\string` and thus stringifying "t" from the phrase "test":

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
{%
⟨character t, due to \string now of category code 12 (other)⟩est.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument
                                                                  %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out the interesting `\secondoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\expandafter` and `\firstoftwo` and thus delivering the space that was inside braces:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter⟨space token⟩\secondoftwo%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\expandafter` and `\secondoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
⟨space token⟩no brace
```

Now `\romannumeral` finds the space token and discards it and aborts gathering digits. As by now it has only found the digit "0" which does not form a positive number, it does silently not deliver any token:

```
%\romannumeral expansion done:
no brace
```

---

For example

```
\UDCheckWhetherBrace{{test}}{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields:

```
\romannumeral0%
\expandafter
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
\expandafter{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
\expandafter{%
\string{test}.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
               %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
\expandafter{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
\expandafter{%
\string{test}.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
               %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out the `\expandafter`-chain and `\string` and thus stringifying the left curly brace/the openening curly brace from the phrase "{test}":

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\secondoftwo%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo.
{%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's opening brace.
{%
⟨character {, due to \string now of category code 12 (other)⟩test}.}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument
                                                                    %  , which itself must be brace-balanced, had an opening-brace as first token.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out the interesting `\secondoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
\secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out the `\expandafter`-chain and `\string`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\firstoftwo{%
\secondoftwo⟨character }, due to \string now of category code 12 (other)⟩\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo}%← This is the interesting \secondoftwo's first argument's closing brace in case the argument 
            %  did not have an opening-brace as first token
{\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}\secondoftwo}%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\firstoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\secondoftwo⟨character }, due to \string now of category code 12 (other)⟩\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\secondoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter\expandafter\firstoftwo{ }{}%
\firstoftwo
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\expandafter` and `\firstoftwo` and thus delivering the space that was inside braces:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
\expandafter⟨space token⟩\firstoftwo%
{brace}{no brace}%
```

yields carrying out `\expandafter` and `\firstoftwo`:

```
%\romannumeral expansion in progress as by now \romannumeral only found the digit 0 and searches for more digits:
⟨space token⟩brace
```

Now `\romannumeral` finds the space token and discards it and aborts gathering digits. As by now it has only found the digit "0" which does not form a positive number, it does silently not deliver any token:

```
%\romannumeral expansion done:
brace
```

Comment: This is much more extensive. I will spend some time understanding and learning from it. I think the idea of checking catcode instead of char code is very interesting and useful. It would be great if some more explanation can be added for the latter case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort explaining how it works.

Comment: This is a very thorough answer.  I am interested in discerning a `{` versus a `\bgroup`; however, I would like to do it to a non-terminated input stream, rather than a macro argument.  That is, if I am digesting an input stream, how to tell the difference between, for example, `\bgroup` and `{\bgroup}`?

Comment: You wish to distinguish an explicit catcode-1-character-token (`{`) from an implicit pendant (`\bgroup`). You can't do this via examining macro arguments because (La)TeX strips off matching pairs of explicit character tokens of category code 1 and 2 that surround an entire argument - be that argument delimited or non-delimited. You can't do this via `\let`/`\futurelet`/`\@ifnextchar` because these are suitable for testing the meanings of consecutive tokens only while with testing meanings you don't get info about explicitness/implicitness of character tokens. So I don't see a reliable way.

Answer (score 8):

Fundamentally you just need to use `\futurelet` as you do for any other look ahead

```
\def\foo{\futurelet\footoken\fooaux}
\def\fooaux{%
  \ifx\footoken\bgroup
     % Brace group
   \else
     % Something else
   \fi
}
```

The only reason this 'looks different' to other peek ahead situations is that you can't use an explicit `{`, but rather the implicit token `\bgroup`.

Comment: That's clear enough and much simpler than I originally imagined.