# Is it possible to set a default value for an argument in a TikZ style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

In a command like:

```
\tikset{qar/.style={draw,rectangle,fill=#1}}
```

is it possible to add a default key value for the option `fill` so that if you have:

```
\node [qar] {};
```

the node will be filled with the default color (for example, red) while if you have:

```
\node [qar={blue}] {};
```

the node will be filled with the selected color?

And what if instead of one there are two arguments like:

```
\tikset{qar/.style 2 args={draw=#2,rectangle,fill=#1}}
```

?

Comment: It becomes interesting if you want to use a mix of optional and mandatory arguments: [Optional arguments in pgfkeys?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39834)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can assign a default value for a key by using the `.default` handler. By setting

```
qar/.style={
    draw,
    rectangle,
    fill=#1
},
qar/.default=red
```

the value `red` will be used whenever `qar` is called without an argument.

The same thing works for keys that take two or more arguments:

```
qar2/.style 2 args={
    rectangle,
    draw=#1, thick,
    fill=#2
},
qar2/.default={blue}{yellow}
```

Comment: How about `qar2/.style args= {#1and#2also#3}{
    rectangle,
    draw=#1, thick,
    fill=#2, text=#3
},` - how do you set default values for that?

Comment: @Make42, it seens that `qar2/.default={1 and 2 also 3}` works...

Comment: Can you also just set defaults partially? So something like: `qar2/.style 2 args={ rectangle, draw=#1, thick, fill=#2 }, qar2/.default={blue}{}`

Comment: With two arguments, is it possible to only specify the first and let the second `#2` be the default value `yellow`? I can't get it to work.