# How to use optional arguments in newcommand with TikZ in the middle of a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I am trying to define a new command that will enable me to automatically format certain parts of my diagram. These parts consist of two nodes added above and below a path. I have a default value that I want for the `pos` key of the nodes, but I'd like to be able to adjust this on the fly if needed with an optional argument. I usually use my new command at the end of my path so that the nodes are placed along the path.

Unfortunately, my naive approach (and the more advanced approach from [Optional arguments in pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39834/32374)) causes a `Did you forget a semicolon?` error from TikZ, so I suspect I'm not going about this in the right way. How can I specify an optional argument to my `newcommand` to change the position of the nodes, or alternatively, how can I use the facilities of TikZ to assign a default value for a key that I can override later?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand*{\testone}[3][0.6]{node[pos={#1}, above] {#2} node[pos={#1}, below] {#3}}
\newcommand*{\testtwo}[2]{node[pos=0.6, above] {#1} node[pos=0.6, below] {#2}}
\newcommand*{\testthr}[2][test]{\node {#1 + #2}}
\newcommand*{\flux}[1]{\pgfkeys{/flux,position,fluxabove,fluxbelow,#1,print}} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39834/32374
\pgfkeys{
    /flux/.is family, /flux,
    position/.default=0.6,
    position/.store in=\position,
    fluxabove/.store in=\fluxabove,
    fluxbelow/.store in=\fluxbelow,
    print/.code={node[pos=\position, above] {\fluxabove} node[pos=\position, below] {\fluxbelow}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) \testone[0.9]{another}{text}; % This doesn't work
\draw (2,0) -- (3,0) \testtwo{text}{text};
\testthr{another};
% \draw (4,0) -- (6,0) \flux{fluxabove=10.0, fluxbelow=9.0}; % This doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Related questions:
[TikZ: \newcommand with optional TikZ options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123694/32374)
[Is it possible to set a default value for an argument in a TikZ style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119453/32374)
[Optional arguments in pgfkeys?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39834/32374)

Answer (score 3):

Stuff defined using `\newcommand` is always going to be problematic inside a TikZ path because of the way TikZ parses path commands.

In this case I think the best way forward is to use keys and in particular the `insert path` key:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\tikzset{%
  test 1/.style args={#1#2#3}{insert path={
    node[pos={#1}, above] {#2} node[pos={#1}, below] {#3}
  }},
  test 2/.style 2 args={insert path={
      node[pos=0.6, above] {#1} node[pos=0.6, below] {#2}
  }},
  flux/.style={flux/.cd,#1, print},
  flux/.cd,
    position/.store in=\position,
    position/.default=0.6, position=,
    fluxabove/.store in=\fluxabove,
    fluxbelow/.store in=\fluxbelow,
    print/.style={/tikz/.cd, insert path={
      node [pos=\position, above] {\fluxabove} node[pos=\position, below] {\fluxbelow}
    }}
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) [test 1={0.9}{another}{text}]; 
\draw (2,0) -- (3,0) [test 2={text}{text}];
\draw (4,0) -- (6,0) [flux={fluxabove=10.0, fluxbelow=9.0}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just one small issue using the third method - it seems the default position is `1.0` instead of what you set as `0.6`. Is this related to the `position=` part? I tried to delete that, but it resulted in an error.

Comment: Actually, setting `position=0.6` and deleting the `position/.default=0.6` does what I want. Could there be any other effects of doing this?