Visualization of positiv or negativ ratings
I want to do a visualization of "bad" or "good" for some parameters.
It should look like this:

But I have no idea on how to get those colored boxes or the format in general.
Do you have any ideas on how this can be done?

Have a look at the pgfplots package

Maybe as a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524447/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64155/pgfplots-need-help-with-complicated-stacked-bar-chart-using-selected-rows-from-d

Please mention that you cross post.

Below, a command \barincell is defined. For --, -, + and ++ it produces a bar which is defined by the command \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn. The first argument defines the x coordinate and the second argument defines the color. For 0, a 0 is placed in the cell.
The command \barincell applies to the cells in the table using the key cmd.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__Erhart_bar_legend_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn #1#2
  {
    \begin { tikzpicture }
      [
        xscale = 2 / 3 ,
        baseline = ( l__Erhart_bar_in_cell_node . base )
      ]
      \int_compare:nNnT { \therownum } = { \therowcount }
        {
          \int_set:Nn \l__Erhart_bar_legend_int { -2 }
          \clist_map_inline:nn { -- , - , 0 , + , ++ }
            {
              \node [ below ] at ( \int_use:N \l__Erhart_bar_legend_int , 0 ) { $##1$ } ;
              \int_incr:N \l__Erhart_bar_legend_int
            }
        }
      \useasboundingbox ( -2 , 0 ) rectangle ( 2 , 0.5 ) ;
      \node ( l__Erhart_bar_in_cell_node ) at ( 0 , 0.25 ) { \phantom { 0 } } ;
      \fill [#2] ( 0 , 0 ) rectangle ( #1 , 0.5 ) ;
      %\draw ( -2 , 0 ) rectangle ( 2 , 0.5 ) ;
    \end { tikzpicture }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \barincell { m }
  {
    \str_case:nnF {#1}
      {
        { -- } { \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn { -2 } { red } }
        { - } { \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn { -1 } { red } }
        { 0 } { $ 0 $ }
        { + } { \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn { 1 } { green!60!black } }
        { ++ } { \__Erhart_bar_in_cell:nn { 2 } { green!60!black } }
      }
      { \errmessage { Wrong~value~in~cell~\therownum , \thecolnum . } }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  cell{2-Z}{2-Z}={cmd=\barincell},
  colspec=l|c|c|c|c,
  rowspec=Q[m]|Q[m]Q[m]Q[m],
  width=542pt
}
 & {Improved energy\\efficiency} & Fuel substitution & {Alternative produc-\\tion technologies} & $\mathrm{CO}_{2}$ separation\\
Development status & ++ & 0 & 0 & +\\
Conditions fulfilled & + & 0 & 0 & -\\
Emission reductions & - & + & + & +\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


