# Changing \newcommand to have optional argument breaks command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, optional-arguments

Simply put, I have a command defined for an edge when using the `tikzpicture` environment.

Command:

```
\newcommand{\bendangleundiredgenodes}[6]{(#3) edge [-] [bend #2=#1] node [#5] {#6} (#4)}
```

Usage:

```
\bendangleundiredgenodes{30}{left}{0}{1}{above}{Test}
```

---

This works perfectly fine. However, if I try to make the first argument optional, then I get an error.

Command:

```
\newcommand{\bendangleundiredgenodes}[6][30]{(#3) edge [-] [bend #2=#1] node [#5] {#6} (#4)}
```

Usages (both fail):

```
\bendangleundiredgenodes{left}{0}{1}{above}{Test}
\bendangleundiredgenodes[30]{left}{0}{1}{above}{Test}
```

Errors (same for both usages):

```
Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?. \bendangleundiredgenodes
Not defining \perthousand.
Not defining \micro.
```

---

Full example usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes, backgrounds, arrows, automata, positioning, decorations.markings, calc}

\newcommand{\bendangleundiredgenodes}[6]{(#3) edge [-] [bend #2=#1] node [#5] {#6} (#4)}

\newenvironment{discretegraph}[2][\Large]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ->,
        >=stealth',
        auto,
        node distance=#2cm,
        thick,
        main node/.style={circle, draw, font=\sffamily#1\bfseries},
        nolooparrow/.style={-, every loop/.append style={-}},
        double arrows/.style args={##1, ##2, ##3}{
            decorate,
            decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 0 with {
                    \coordinate (ta-base-1) at (0,##3pt);
                    \coordinate (ta-base-2) at (0,-##3pt);
                },
                mark=at position 1 with {
                    \draw[##1] (ta-base-1) -- (0,##3pt); \draw[##2] (ta-base-2) -- (0,-##3pt);
                }
            }
        }, every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]]
}
{;\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{discretegraph}[\normalsize]{3}
        \node[main node] (0) [] {};
        \node[main node] (1) [right of = 0] {};
        
        \path
        \bendangleundiredgenodes{30}{left}{0}{1}{above}{Test}
        
    \end{discretegraph}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `\path` performs a single expansion of the token following it and this works with the `\newcommand` defined with no optional argument. It can't work with optional arguments.

Comment: commands with optional arguments are not expandable, they don't work in various places. You could try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`  from xparse instead (untested as you didn't provide a complete example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added complete example

Comment: And did you try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Maybe I am being foolish, but I cannot find the documentation for \ NewExpandableDocumentCommand, even in the `xparse` documentation.

Comment: in my version it is on page 14 of xparse.pdf (current texlive).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not think I am doing this correctly: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\bendangleundiredgenodes}{ o m m m m m }{ (#3) edge [-] [bend #2=#1] node [#5] {#6} (#4) }`

Comment: @SabdulUlahi It should be `O{30}` instead of `o`, but it doesn't work anyway, because it needs several expansion steps, whereas `\path` only does one.

Comment: @egreg Ah, I see. That's unfortunate to hear. I suppose I'll keep the long command then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others discussed in the comments, you cannot use macros with optional arguments in Ti*k*Z paths. However, it seems to me that you don't really gain much by using this macro anyways: It is not any shorter than just inputting the actual path specification.

Instead, you should take advantage of `pgfkeys`, which is how Ti*k*Z drawings are meant to be styled. This also applies to your `discretegraph` environment. Here's how I would approach it.

- Replace `discretegraph` by a key, I named it `discrete graph`.
- I chose to keep the node font as an option to `discrete graph` and ditch the `node distance`. If you need to change the `node distance`, do it explicitly. (Explicit is usually better than implicit anyways.)
- You could use `discrete graph/.default` to set the default font size, but it is simpler and clearer to just put `\Large` in the definitions and allow overriding this with the argument, so I did that.
- Make another key for you edges. I called it `sabdul`, obviously you should rename it to something corresponding to what they represent. There are different avenues of making it configurable. I followed a style present elsewhere in Ti*k*Z and made a second key `sabdul'` bending the other way.
- Don't use numbers as node names. While it is legal, it looks like an incomplete coordinate which is confusing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\tikzset{
  discrete graph/.style={
    ->,
    >=stealth',
    auto,
    thick,
    main node/.style={circle, draw, font={\sffamily\bfseries\Large#1}},
    nolooparrow/.style={-, every loop/.append style={-}},
    double arrows/.style args={##1, ##2, ##3}{
      decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position 0 with {
          \coordinate (ta-base-1) at (0,##3pt);
          \coordinate (ta-base-2) at (0,-##3pt);
        },
        mark=at position 1 with {
          \draw[##1] (ta-base-1) -- (0,##3pt); \draw[##2] (ta-base-2) -- (0,-##3pt);
        }
      }
    },
    every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small},
  },
  @sabdul/.style 2 args={
    -,
%    bend angle=30, % is the default anyway
    bend #2=#1,
  },
  @sabdul/.default=30,
  sabdul/.style={@sabdul={#1}{left}},
  sabdul'/.style={@sabdul={#1}{right}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [
    discrete graph=\normalsize,
    node distance=3cm,
    ]
  \node [main node] (a) {foo};
  \node [main node] (b) [right of=a] {};
  \path (a) edge [sabdul] node [above] {test} (b);
  \path (a) edge [sabdul'=60] node [below] {another test} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

---

It is usually best to avoid needing keys with several or optional arguments, like I did here. If you really want to, you should read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39834/48973). Using the keys from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518067/48973), you could instead define something like

```latex
\tikzset{
  sabdul/.style with optarg with default value={left}{-, bend #1=#2},
}
```

I would recommend the former approach, though.