# Environment in \NewEnviron style, with key-value parameters

Tags: environments, key-value

I want to define an environment that read its content before processing (like `\newEnviron` from the package `environ`) but also that allows key-value parameters (like `\newkeyenvironment` from the package `keycommand` that I usually use).

How should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with [`keyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval) and [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\define@key{mykeys}{font}{\def\envfont{#1}}%
\makeatother
\NewEnviron{myenv}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{mykeys}{font=\normalfont,#1}% Set default and updated keys
  \envfont\BODY% Set contents in font \envfont
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{myenv}[font=\bfseries\itshape]
\lipsum[1]
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

The above example sets the font of the environment `myenv` using a key-value given by `font`. The key-value is stored in the family `mykeys` with `font=\normalfont` being the default. For more on setting key-value pairs, see [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764)

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides *Lorem Ipsum*-style dummy text.

Comment: thanks a lot. By the way, is there a way to define a key, which would act as a boolean swithc, but which one could call with `[switch]` instead of `[switch =true]` ?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing special: assuming you've defined a `bar` family of keys

```
\NewEnviron{foo}[1]{%
  \setkeys{bar}{#1}%
  do something with \BODY
}
```

or

```
\NewEnviron{foo}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{bar}{#1}%
  do something with \BODY
}
```

will allow the syntax

```
\begin{foo}{key1=value1,key2=value2}
text
\end{foo}
```

or

```
\begin{foo}[key1=value1,key2=value2]
text
\end{foo}
```

respectively. Which one to prefer depends on many factors: if the user *has* to supply at least a key-value pair, then the first form is recommended.

I've used `\setkeys`, as I don't know how `keycommand` works (it should be very similar, anyway).

Comment: ok, thanks, i had never used `\setkeys`, because i found the syntax of `keycommand` easier. So, I have to read how to use `\setkeys`. From which package is it ?

Comment: `keycommand` loads `xkeyval`, which is an extension of `keyval`. I recommend looking at the documentation of `keyval` which is quite neat about defining and setting keys.