# How to make this pgfkeys code more compact and streamlined?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, pgfkeys

I have just managed to create my first command with `pgfkeys`. I defined a command `\myset`, whose purpose is to make (for example)

```
\myset[big]{abc}
```

correspond to

```
\bigl\{abc\bigr\}
```

Part of my goal was to do this in a way that would easily let me create variants later, using different delimiters; in particular, I didn't want my `\pgfkeys` code to refer to the `\{` and `\}`.

Working from [this TeX.SE thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/27533) and [the relevant section of the PGF manual](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=481), here is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{/delimitersizes/.is family, /delimitersizes,
 default/.style = {auto},
 auto/.style = {leftsize = auto, rightsize = auto},
 big/.style = {leftsize = big, rightsize = big},
 bigg/.style = {leftsize = bigg, rightsize = bigg},
 Big/.style = {leftsize = Big, rightsize = Big},
 Bigg/.style = {leftsize = Bigg, rightsize = Bigg},
 leftsize/.style = {leftdictionary/#1/.get = \leftdelimitersize},
 rightsize/.style = {rightdictionary/#1/.get = \rightdelimitersize},
leftdictionary/.cd,
  big/.initial = \bigl,
  bigg/.initial = \biggl,
  Big/.initial = \Bigl,
  Bigg/.initial = \Biggl,
  auto/.initial = \left, }
\pgfkeys{/delimitersizes, rightdictionary/.cd,
  big/.initial = \bigr,
  bigg/.initial = \biggr,
  Big/.initial = \Bigr,
  Bigg/.initial = \Biggr,
  auto/.initial = \right, }

\newcommand{\myset}[2][]{
\pgfkeys{delimitersizes, default, #1}
\leftdelimitersize\{#2\rightdelimitersize\} }

\begin{document}
$\myset[big]{abc}$
\end{document}
```

This functions as it is supposed to, but considering the finished product, it seems like there's a significant amount of "code duplication", and shuffling around of information before getting to use it. I realize this is a rather open-ended question, but can people suggest how to improve this code to make it more compact and streamlined?

Comment: You are re-inventing the wheel, with squares. Take a look at [`\DeclarePairedDelimiter`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=declarepaireddelimiter) from the `mathtools` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more streamlined but I'm not sure if using pgf was a requirement in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\myset[2][big]{\csname#1l\endcsname\{#2\csname#1r\endcsname\}}

\begin{document}

$\myset{abc}$  $\myset[Bigg]{xyz}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think David has the right of it, but if you want to do *something* like this with `pgfkeys`, here is the style I like.  This took me way too long to get right, though I think a year ago, before I got out of practice, it wouldn't have.  This is also an argument against doing things this way for something so simple.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{/delimitersizes/.cd,
  util/create/.style = {
    util/name = #1,
    util/dict =
    {#1}
    {\csname#1l\endcsname}
    {\csname#1r\endcsname}
  },
  util/name/.style = {
    #1/.style = {
      leftsize = #1,
      rightsize = #1
    }
  },
  util/dict/.style n args = {3}{
    leftdictionary/#1/.initial/.expand once = #2,
    rightdictionary/#1/.initial/.expand once = #3
  },
  leftsize/.style = {
    leftdictionary/#1/.get =  \leftdelimitersize
  },
  rightsize/.style = {
    rightdictionary/#1/.get = \rightdelimitersize
  },
  default/.style = auto,
  util/create/.list = {big,bigg,Big,Bigg},
  % Treat auto specially
  util/name = auto,
  util/dict = {auto}{\noexpand\left}{\noexpand\right}
}

\newcommand{\myset}[2][]{
  \pgfkeys{/delimitersizes/.cd,default,#1}
  \leftdelimitersize\{#2\rightdelimitersize\}
}
\begin{document}

$\myset[big]{abc}$
$\myset[Big]{abc}$
$\myset[bigg]{abc}$
$\myset[Bigg]{abc}$

\end{document}
```

Basically, you create a bunch of utility keys that do the work of defining the keys you *actually* use, and then call the utility keys repeatedly.  This is facilitated by the ever-useful `.list` handler, which I guess is the core of the code-repetition reduction strategy.  Note that if you were going to call keys that made assignments via .loop, those assignments would have to be made globally or else (since `\foreach` is run in a group) they would be lost.