# xparse and key value arguments

Tags: macros, xparse, key-value

I'm trying to learn how to do macros.

I want to use `xparse` as it seems the most powerful tool.
I also want named arguments, as numbered arguments make me, as a programmer, uncomfortable.

I had some ideas like:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myMacro} {o o}
{
   \DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo} {} {#1}
   \DeclareDocumentCommand{\bar} {} {#2}
   The foo argument was \foo and the bar argument was \bar

}
```

But this wouldn't work, because of nesting and wouldn't extend to DocumentEnviroments, I guess since different scoping for beginning and end sections.

My goal is to have some sections of a document that are highly structured.
For example I might have a list of movies, which have parameters like title, date, director etc.
and I might manipulate them in complex ways (perhaps building them into a paragraph),
and I don't want to have to remember which order the parameters were in when defining this.

Perhaps I am thinking wrong for a LaTeX user, I guess in many programming languages you need to know the order when invoking a function (though in this case, I would like to use the name of arguments when invoking - for clarity)

Comment: See also [Latex, named parameter macros](https://web.archive.org/web/20140707003448/http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27636/latex-named-parameter-macros).

Comment: Thanks, I was meaning to link that here, after i created it, but I got distracted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a very elementary view on LaTeX's key-value system using [`keyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval), similar to what was presented in [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval,xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{keyval,xparse}

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{mymacro}{first}{\def\mm@first{#1}}
\define@key{mymacro}{second}{\def\mm@second{#1}}
\define@key{mymacro}{third}{\def\mm@third{#1}}
\define@key{mymacro}{last}{\def\mm@last{#1}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\myMacro}{m}{%
  \begingroup%
  % ========= KEY DEFAULTS + new ones =========
  \setkeys{mymacro}{first={FIRST arg},second={SECOND arg},third={THIRD arg},last={LAST arg},#1}%
  First arg: \mm@first \par
  Second arg: \mm@second \par
  Third arg: \mm@third \par
  Last arg: \mm@last
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myMacro{last=LaSt,first=FiRsT} \par \hrulefill

\myMacro{} \par \hrulefill

\myMacro{third={$x^2$ \textbf{stuff}},second={}}
\end{document}
```

It should be evident that using a key-value approach removes the requirement to remember the order of the keys. That is, unless the keys have some interaction with one another.

Grouping (via `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`) localizes the changes to the keys. However, you can make things available globally. It just depends on your application. Moreover, it would be possible to adapt the key-values to actually create key-macros that you can re-use. This may be helpful if you have a area in your document where you perform a bunch of declarations, and want to re-use them later.

The above example translates just as well to document environments.

More extensions are provided by [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval), [`ltxkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxkeys) and even `l3keys` from [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3) (see [Programming key–value in `expl3`](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-l3keys.pdf)).

---

Here's a practical example of using key-values to store data regarding movies through a movie declaration (`\newMovie{<tag>}{<key-values>}`) and printing it (`\showMovie{<tag>}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval,xparse,url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{keyval,xparse,url}

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{movie}{title}{\expandafter\def\csname \movietag @title\endcsname{#1}}
\define@key{movie}{releaseyear}{\expandafter\def\csname \movietag @releaseyear\endcsname{#1}}
\define@key{movie}{genre}{\expandafter\def\csname \movietag @genre\endcsname{#1}}
\define@key{movie}{url}{\expandafter\def\csname \movietag @url\endcsname{#1}}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newMovie}{m m}{%
  % ========= KEY DEFAULTS + new ones =========
  \def\movietag{#1}% Store movie tag (used when setting/storing keys)
  \setkeys{movie}{title={},releaseyear={},genre={},url={},#2}% Create keys
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\showMovie}{m}{%
  \textbf{\csname #1@title\endcsname} (\csname #1@releaseyear\endcsname),
  \textit{\csname #1@genre\endcsname},
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\url\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname #1@url\endcsname}.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Movie declarations
\newMovie{anchorman2}{
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/},
  releaseyear=2013,
  title={Anchorman: The Legend Continues},
  genre=Comedy}
\newMovie{lego}{
  title={The Lego Movie},
  releaseyear=2014,
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/},
  genre={Animation, Action, Comedy}}
\newMovie{magic}{
  title={Now You See Me},
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/},
  releaseyear=2013,
  genre={Crime, Thriller}}

% Show movie details
\showMovie{magic}

\showMovie{anchorman2}

\showMovie{lego}

\end{document}
```

There are other (perhaps better) ways of dealing with this, but again, this is just to showcase what you can do with key-value approaches to macros (and databases).

Comment: When `mymacro` defines macros to be used outside the command localization with `\begingroup ... \endgroup` does not work, as the macros would be localized aswell.

Comment: @HeinrichOdy: You could define them to survive outside the group as well...

Comment: Hi @Werner, could you please explain how to display only the first genre from the set of genres? I am trying to pass an array to a new command and process it inside it. Thanks!

Comment: @gauravgupta: How would you define a "set of genres"?

Answer (score 6):

An implementation entirely in `expl3`, using key-value pairs and property lists.

Each `\newMovie` command defines a property list and stores the values. Then `\showMovie` displays them in the preferred order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,url}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% keys
\keys_define:nn { oxinabox/movies }
 {
  title .tl_set:N = \l_oxinabox_title_tl,
  releaseyear .tl_set:N = \l_oxinabox_releaseyear_tl,
  genre .tl_set:N = \l_oxinabox_genre_tl,
  url .tl_set:N = \l_oxinabox_url_tl,
 }

% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\newMovie}{m m}
 {
  \oxinabox_newmovie:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\showMovie}{m}
 {
  \oxinabox_showmovie:n { #1 }
 }

% internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \oxinabox_newmovie:nn #1 #2
 {
  \group_begin: % keep the assignment to the keys local
  \prop_new:c { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop }
  \keys_set:nn { oxinabox/movies } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnV { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop } { title } \l_oxinabox_title_tl
  \prop_gput:cnV { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop } { releaseyear } \l_oxinabox_releaseyear_tl
  \prop_gput:cnV { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop } { genre } \l_oxinabox_genre_tl
  \prop_gput:cnV { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop } { url } \l_oxinabox_url_tl
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new:Npn \oxinabox_getvalue:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_oxinabox_movie_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \oxinabox_showmovie:n #1
 {
  \par\noindent
  \textbf{ \oxinabox_getvalue:nn { #1 } { title } }, ~ %
  \textbf{ \oxinabox_getvalue:nn { #1 } { releaseyear } }, ~ %
  \textbf{ \oxinabox_getvalue:nn { #1 } { genre } },
  \\
  \use:x { \exp_not:N \url { \oxinabox_getvalue:nn { #1 } { url } } }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

% Movie declarations
\newMovie{anchorman2}{
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/},
  releaseyear=2013,
  title={Anchorman: The Legend Continues},
  genre=Comedy}
\newMovie{lego}{
  title={The Lego Movie},
  releaseyear=2014,
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/},
  genre={Animation, Action, Comedy}}
\newMovie{magic}{
  title={Now You See Me},
  url={http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1670345/},
  releaseyear=2013,
  genre={Crime, Thriller}}

% Show movie details
\showMovie{magic}

\showMovie{anchorman2}

\showMovie{lego}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to Werner for the data. ;-)

[image]

Comment: Hello, this solution does not work with the latest version of xparse (from TeXLive 2018 update)...saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Yes, it used a now deprecated command: things change in five years. Thanks for noting.