# How to define a function with optional key-value arguments

Tags: macros, key-value

I have setup a function called *quickfigure* which has the purpose of inserting a centered image with a one-line command:

```
\newcommand{\quickfigure}[2] {
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{#1}
        \caption{#2}
    \end{figure}
}
```

This function is used as follows;

```
\quickfigure{img/testImage.png}{Test image}
```

I would like this function to accept optional arguments to define width and height of the image, as well as a label. The syntax is desired to be something like;

```
\quickfigure[width=0.6, label=img:test]{img/testImage.png}{Test image}
```

How would I go about setting this up? I need a push in the right direction. Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks everyone for the ideas, this is my solution;

```
\includepackage{keyval}
\includepackage{ifthen}

\newlength{\qf@width}
\define@key{quickfigure}{width}{\setlength\qf@width{#1}}
\define@key{quickfigure}{label}{\def\qf@label{#1}}

\newcommand{\quickfigure}[3][] {
    \setkeys{quickfigure}{width=0.6\linewidth,label=\@empty}
    \setkeys{quickfigure}{#1}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\qf@width]{#2}
        \caption{#3}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\qf@label}{}}{}{\label{\qf@label}}
    \end{figure}
}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to create a command with key values?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764)

Comment: @Werner This is a case where the optional argument seems to be passed directly to `\includegraphics`

Comment: I'm not sure you gain anything by hiding the document's structure into a macro.

Comment: @egreg: Just partially, since `label` doesn't exist for `\includegraphics`. It would have to be managed differently. And true, it was a mild approach at pushing towards a solution.

Comment: @egreg I experienced that I use this structure very often

Comment: @Wilco: You could combine your `\setkeys` as `\setkeys{quickfigure}{width=.6\linewidth,label=\@empty,#1}`. Note that you are required to use a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair with your current definition.

Comment: You need `%` at the end of most lines in your definition

Answer (score 3):

Or you could always do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,xparse}


\NewDocumentCommand\quickfigure{O{width=0.6\linewidth} m o m}{%
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
        \caption{#4}\IfNoValueTF{#3}{\relax}{\label{#3}}%
    \end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\quickfigure{example-image-a}{Test image}

\quickfigure[width=20pt, height=100pt]{example-image-a}[img:test]{Test image}


\end{document}
```

[image: Two images]

Comment: You can also simply say `\IfValueT{#3}{\label{#3}}` or, equivalently, `\IfNoValueF{#3}{\label{#3}}`

Comment: @egreg Interesting. Thank you. Is that documented elsewhere? The `xparse` documentation I have only mentions `\IfValueTF{}{}{}` and `\IfNoValueTF{}{}{}`.

Comment: It *is* documented, albeit in a perhaps cryptic form; if you look closely, you'll see that `TF` in `\IfNoValueTF` (in the margin) are in italics and underlined in red. This is a shorthand for saying that either letter (and the corresponding argument) can be removed. The convention is described in the LaTeX3 interface documentation; it should probably be added also in the documentation of `xparse`.

Comment: @cfr Thank you for this suggestion! This is a very nice solution. Is it possible to have the optional label argument in the first parameter and extract it before passing it to `\includegraphics`?

Comment: @Wilco Possible, yes. But I would use the link Werner provided in that case since there is no point in reinventing the wheel. That is, if you want to set it up to parse key-value pairs, you are best off using a tool designed for that. You could, of course, combine one of those solutions with the solution here. Just drop the second optional argument and run the first one through the tool of your choice.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I have to say, that's pretty unobvious to somebody trying to get to grips with that stuff. Not only did I not know where that was explained, it wasn't obvious to me that anything in particular was meant by it which might be in need of explanation. A little more obvious of a hint would certainly be appreciated! (I have actually looked through the interface documentation but it seemed so far beyond my grasp that I decided reading it was something to aspire to rather than something to actually attempt in the here-and-now.)