# Two parts caption in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I'm using [this template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article) to write my report. I'm trying to add a listoffigures so I added those lines in the `.cls` file:

```
\newlength{\lofsep} 
\setlength\lofsep{2pc}

\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{figure}[\lofsep]
  {\addvspace{4pt}\color{color1}\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{\lofsep}}
  {}
  {\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\ \thecontentspage}
  []
```

… and it works fine !

The thing is that I want my caption to be in two parts :

- The actual caption
- The author credit

It would be nice if I could get something like that :

1    **My caption** - *John Smith* ........................... 5

OR

1    **My caption** ................................................. 5

*John Smith*

because for now it's just :

1    My caption - John Smith ............................. 5

and it's not really readable.

So I thought I could split the `\contentslabel` in `\tiltecontents` but it appears that `\contentslabel` is not given in `\tiltecontents`.

Hope it's clear enough, thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide some information on how you would mark it up in the code; for example, do you want to use `\caption[\author{<author name>}-\mycapt{Caption}]{Actual caption}`...

Comment: Yes ! That solution would be really nice ! I thought about it but I really don't know where to start. I'm just beginning with those "advanced LaTeX technics" !

Comment: Does anyone has some starting points/websites to look at ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that defines the command `\mycaption` that has the following syntax

```
\mycaption[author=<name>,toc=<caption for toc>]{<caption>}
```

The default value for `<author>` is `Friedrich`, and the default value for the `<toc>` key is `<caption>`. For a very thorough tutorial on the [`keyval`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/keyval) package see the documentation and [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values), for example.

[image: screenshot]

You might prefer to  renew the `caption` command, but you'd have to be careful if you were going to load either the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) or [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) packages, which is why I left it alone.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyval}% http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval

\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{mycaption}{toc}{\def\friedrich@toc{#1}}
\define@key{mycaption}{author}{\def\friedrich@author{#1}}
% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{mycaption}{toc={},author=Friedrich}%
% ========= MYCAPTION COMMAND  =========
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2][]{%
    \ifx\\#1\\% check if #1 is empty
        \caption{#2} % just a regular caption
    \else
        \setkeys{mycaption}{#1}% Set new keys
        \ifx\friedrich@toc\empty
            \def\friedrich@toc{#2}
        \fi
        \caption[{\bfseries\friedrich@toc}-{\itshape\friedrich@author}]{#2}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \mycaption[toc=caption for toc,author=Fried]{actual caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \mycaption[toc=caption for toc (note the default author)]{actual caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \mycaption[author=cmh]{actual caption (used in toc and caption)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \mycaption{actual caption (no keys specified)}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
  \mycaption[toc={group the caption to use $=$}]{actual caption (used in toc and caption)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was expecting for ! Thank you very much.