# Defining a macro with a variable number of arguments

Tags: macros

I want to define a macro that defines a series of other macros, each of which takes a variable (but in any given document fixed) number of arguments. I know that I can do this using something like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand\MakeCommands[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\relax%
  \or\newcommand\MyCommand[1]{##1}%
  \or\newcommand\MyCommand[2]{##1, ##2}%
  \or\newcommand\MyCommand[3]{##1, ##2, ##3}%
  \or\newcommand\MyCommand[3]{##1, ##2, ##3, ##4}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
  \MakeCommands{3}
  \MyCommand{one}{two}{three}
\end{document}
```

but I am sure that there is a better way of doing this...I get the feeling that it is time I learnt to use keys...

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: It would be definetly easier `\MyCommand{one,two,three}`, and let TeX process the comma list separating items with `, `.

Comment: ...perhaps more appropriate is using a key-value approach: `\MyCommand{one=first, two=second, three=third}`.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with those arguments; if it's just printing them separated by comma and space, then I don't see why you'd want a macro. If it's for printing them with a variable separator, then it's another matter, but definitely not to be solved with a variable number of arguments which has the problem of “where should I stop?”

Comment: @egreg This is a cut-down MWE. The real application is more than just printing...

Comment: @Werner Thank you. What you are suggesting is the right approach. I thought I should be using keys, but I didn't quite realise how. Am happy to accept this as an answer is you want to post it as one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest creating a number of keys that the user can decide to use or not. It also allows them the freedom to specify only a portion of them, in any order they wish. Here's a quick example using [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@cmdkey{mycmd}{one}[one]{}
\define@cmdkey{mycmd}{two}[two]{}
\define@cmdkey{mycmd}{three}[three]{}
\define@cmdkey{mycmd}{four}[four]{}
% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{mycmd}{one,two,three,four}% Defaults
\newcommand{\MyCommand}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setkeys{mycmd}{two=SECOND,#1}% Set defaults for this macro + new keys
  \texttt{one}: \cmdKV@mycmd@one;
  \texttt{two}: \cmdKV@mycmd@two;
  \texttt{three}: \cmdKV@mycmd@three;
  \texttt{four}: \cmdKV@mycmd@four
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\MyCommand{one}

\MyCommand{two=second,one=first,three=third}

\MyCommand{four=Last}

\end{document}
```

As reference, see [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764).

Answer (score 6):

My answer is only Werner's answer by another tools: instead of usage of `xkeyval`, there are five lines of code with TeX primitives. The result is exactly the same as Werner's result.

```
\def\kv#1{\expandafter\ifx\csname kv:#1\endcsname \relax \expandafter\kvunknown
   \else \csname kv:#1\expandafter\endcsname\fi }
\def\kvunknown{???}
\def\kvscan #1#2=#3,{\ifx#1,\else \kvdef{kv:#1#2}{#3}\expandafter\kvscan\fi}
\def\kvdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}

\def\mymacro#1{\kvscan one=one, two=SECOND, three=three, four=four,,=,% implicit values
   \kvscan#1,,=,% actual values
   {\tt one}: \kv{one}; {\tt two}: \kv{two}; {\tt three}: \kv{three}; {\tt four}: \kv{four}
}

\mymacro{}

\mymacro{two=second, one=first, three=third}

\mymacro{four=Last}
```

[image: Werner's picture]

If somebody will comment this as reinventing the wheel, I disagree. Writing such five lines is much more simple for me than the reading 72 pages of `xkeyval` documentation.

Comment: I think this is indeed reinventing the wheel because reading the TeXBook (many more than 72 pages) to understand expansion is significantly more work than understanding how a package is used. But still a nice one anyway, I like its simplicity for this task.

Comment: But after reading the TeXbook I am able to solve much more things than only `xkeyval` features described at 72 pages and basically implemented by five lines-:). When I count up all pages of documentation of all packages where a few lines of implementation is possible then the total number of pages will be many times more than pages in the TeXbook.

Comment: The answer is the same for this particular input, but if you put white space about `,` you'll get differences, normalizing white space while controlling how many `{}` are needed to get a `,` into the value is usually the larger part of a keyval parser, splitting up on , and = is the simple bit, as you show.

Comment: The criticisms above not withstanding, I always enjoy reading Wipet's solutions. Děkuji!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If users need to remove white space (for example around =) then they can use `\replacestrings{ =}{=}\replacestrings{= }{=}` (the `\replacestrings` from OPmac) as is shown at my site of various pakages-like plain TeX simple solutions: http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks.html#keyval

Comment: Who needs an OS if you know Assembly right? :)

Comment: @percusse I have written already that Assemler -> OS and TeX -> macros isn't good comparison. You can forget the Assembler when you are using OS (new level of abstraction) but you cannot forget TeX when you are using TeX macros. If people do this (forget TeX) then they have problems and we can see these problems here at tex.sx.com. But I hope that your comment was only joke...

Comment: Yes it was a joek but I don't agree with your comparison. Memory leaks and garbage collection and many more are also essential things that you shouldn't forget however high level languages are there for a reason not out of laziness. So each time falling back to lowest level is not essential but a personal preference. IF you are using heavy computations yes Fortran is the King but you won't program a Database application or data mining in Fortran if you know what you are doing. That's why this site exists where experts teach step by step the inner workings to others. That doesn't mean that ...

Comment: everybody should learn all the intricacies of TeX obscurity.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [Werner's approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207337) but using `expl3`:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { one , two ,  three , four }
  {
    \keys_define:nn {  mycmd } { #1 .tl_set:c = { l__mycmd_ #1 _tl } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \MyCommand #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \keys_set:nn { mycmd } {#1}
      Key~values~are:
     \clist_map_inline:nn { one , two ,  three , four }
       { ~ ##1 ~ = ~  ` \tl_to_str:c  { l__mycmd_ ##1 _tl } ' }
    \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\MyCommand{one = a}

\end{document}
```

The reason I'd favour the `expl3` key module (`l3keys`) over `xkeyval` is that the behaviour of `l3keys` with respect to brace retention, space stripping and the category codes of `,` and `=` in arguments is all very well-defined and clear. I also find the `xkyeval` interface rather awkward (somewhat ironic): `l3keys` shares with `pgfkeys`.

(The above work with other formats if you use `\input expl3-generic` rather than `\RequirePackage{expl3}`. If you are definitely targetting LaTeX I'd use `xparse` for the user interface.)

Comment: I've defined the keys here using a comma list mapping as it's convenient: in a real case you might well want to do them using a keyval list (part of the point of `l3keys`).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know in what sense this is useful, but here's an option with `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { g g g g g g g g g }
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \IfValueT { #1 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 } }
  \IfValueT { #2 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #2 } }
  \IfValueT { #3 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #3 } }
  \IfValueT { #4 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #4 } }
  \IfValueT { #5 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #5 } }
  \IfValueT { #6 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #6 } }
  \IfValueT { #7 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #7 } }
  \IfValueT { #8 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #8 } }
  \IfValueT { #9 } { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #9 } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { , ~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\begin{document}
\mycommand{one}{two}{three}
\mycommand{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}{six}{seven}
\mycommand{one}{two}
\end{document}
```

It takes up to nine arguments, and separates them with commas.

Comment: Thanks. This is better than my mock MWE, but I;ll try using keys following Werner's suggestion.

Comment: We don't know what you want to achieve, so saying that the best solution is a comma separated list is not a “suggestion” but a “blind shot” to see if it works. You could add details about what you want to achieve, you may receive better answers about the best “interface”.

Comment: I think you meant `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: @Manuel Sorry, I wasn't trying to obscure. The application I have has several components, so it would be quite lengthy to explain (and I haven't worked out all the details year). This aspect of it is quite simple, so I tried to distil what I need in a simple MWE. Of course, you are right in that the "best" solution depends on what I am really trying to do... Thanks again!