# How to make a command with three optional arguments?

Tags: optional-arguments

I'm sorry for my English, but, anyway, I'd like to know how to create a new command with three optional arguments? 
I wanna get what is shown on the picture. I have some other ways how to achieve that, but they are not so comfy as I want. I tried to use `twoopt` package but there're only two possible optional arguments so it didn't satisfy me. I would like that "1", "2" and "l" to be optional so that I just could put in the text something like `\fff` and get exactly what is on the picture or, e.g., to put `\fff[][][3]` and get what I need. Are there any ways to make what I'm asking about? 
Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: You can make a new command with 3 optinal arguments with`\newcommand{name-of-command}[number of options]{definition}`

Comment: No, you're wrong. This allows you to create a command with only ONE optional arguments and from 1 to 9 mandatory arguments.

Comment: Not quite. One optional  and up to 8 mandatory. Remember #1 still counts at we can have at most up to #9

Comment: Have a look at the xparse package, then this is easy. But you still need a lot of typing because of the empty []'s. Might be better with a key-val based interface.

Comment: @MGMKLML maybe, I don't understand yet, but if you try making another command for 1,2 and l, something like `\newcommand{\eee}{\stackrel{1\to2}{l}}`, then add this new command to where you want ...

Comment: @juanuni yep, you just don't understand, but thanks))).

Comment: @daleif I've tried xparse but I always get some errors. Could you give me an exact example of how it should be used? Thank you.

Comment: See the xparse manual. You are making a macro with ooo, and then you have to test on these to determine whether 1, 2 or 3 optional args was given, via `\IfNoValueTF{#1}{}{}` etc.

Comment: But you should really rethink this. It will become a major pain in the but in the long run to use an interface like this. Key-val based interface will be easier to read and work with.

Comment: @MGMKLML It would be good to see how you produced the picture and how it should appear in context: is the "A" sitting on the baseline? What should happen if the optional arguments are missing? As it stands, the question is a bit vague.

Comment: @daleif what're you talking about? I mean "key-val"? What's this?

Comment: @egreg the picture is produced with the following code: `\newcommandtwoopt{\fff}[3][1][2]{\underset{{{\stackrel{#1 \rightarrow #2}{\scriptscriptstyle #3}}}}{A}}`

Comment: See for example the xkeyval package. Or the interface the `\includegraphics` macro uses.

Comment: @MGMKLML You don't say what should happen if the arguments are missing.

Comment: @egreg if they're missing then it should have the default view (like on the picture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fff { O{1} O{A} O{2} } {#1 \underset{l}{\overset{#2}{\to}} #3 }
\begin{document}
\[
\fff \quad \fff[3][B][4]
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. That's exactly what I wanted to get. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here a solution without `xparse` - actually it exhibits how superior `xparse` is compared with the traditional approach:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter

\def\fff{%
  \bgroup
  \@ifnextchar[{\@fff}{\@fff[]}%
}

\def\@fff[#1]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \def\@fffi{1}%
  \else
    \def\@fffi{#1}%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\@@fff}{\@@fff[]}%
}

\def\@@fff[#1]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \def\@fffii{A}%
  \else
    \def\@fffii{#1}%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\@@@fff}{\@@@fff[]}%
}

\def\@@@fff[#1]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
    \def\@fffiii{2}%
  \else
    \def\@fffiii{#1}%
  \fi
  \ensuremath{\@fffi
    \underset{l}{\overset{\@fffii}{\to}}\@fffiii}%
  \egroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
\fff \quad \fff[][][]\quad \fff[9]\quad \fff[][Z] \\
\fff[][][5]\quad \fff[3][B][4]\quad \fff
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can define something like this:

```
\newcommand{\parcial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
```

to make

```
\parcial{f}{x}:
```

[image]

Note that `[2]` is for the quantity of variables. Note the order of variables too. You can play with this code to make your own new commands.

Comment: Again, this is the way where I gotta write arguments everytime. I would like to get the command where I don't have to put arguments if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always more convenient to use a key-value approach when trying to handle more than one optional argument. Here's an implementation using [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval,amsmath}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{myfam}{left}{}
\define@cmdkey{myfam}{right}{}
\define@cmdkey{myfam}{bottom}{}

\newcommand{\fff}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{myfam}{%
    left=1,right=2,bottom=l,% Defaults
    #1}%
    \underset{%
      \overset
        {\cmdKV@myfam@left \rightarrow \cmdKV@myfam@right}
        {\scriptscriptstyle \cmdKV@myfam@bottom}%
      }{#2}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$ \fff{A} \quad \fff[left=a]{A} \quad \fff[right=b]{A} \quad \fff[left=c,right=d]{A} \quad \fff[left=e,right=f,bottom=h]{A} $

\end{document}
```

I've made one argument to `\fff` mandatory, but that can also be hard-coded in the function, or made a key-value option.

Reference: [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764)

Comment: Thank you. It looks nice, but I hardly understand the principles of creating such commands with xparse). There're so many unknown things for me)

Comment: @MGMKLML: I don't use `xparse` in my solution. Only `xkeyval`, although using `keyval` would suffice (with some change in the code).

Comment: Excuse me, but where can I read about the xkeyval and about creating such things by xkeyval? It is very desirable to read somewhere where it's clear and evident.

Comment: @MGMKLML: You should read the linked post in my answer.