# \newcommand for a function with one optional argument inside other optional argument

Tags: macros, xstring

SX. In this case, I want to create a `\newcommand` named `\fun` for function.

My problem arises when I use a `\ fun` command again with the name `f` (the letter f is widely used in my document) and avoid the first definition because otherwise, I will get the first case.

## Minimal example

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\rn}[1][n]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{\mathbb{R}}%
        {2}{\mathbb{R}^{2}}%
        {3}{\mathbb{R}^{3}}%
        {n}{\mathbb{R}^{n}}
        {#1}{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}
        % You can add a finite number of more cases :)
   }%
}%

\newcommand{\fun}[3][f]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{
        {f}{f\colon\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}}
        {g}{g\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}}
        {#1}{#1\colon #2\rightarrow #3}
% Maybe "othercase" can generate case like f or g.
    }
}

\begin{document}

If I use $f$ function like this $\fun[f]{\rn}{\rn[m]}$,

but I expect to use a function called $f\colon\rn\rightarrow\rn[m]$.

This example works fine, e.g, $\fun[\omega]{\rn}{\rn[1]}$ but I want to use 
this command

%\fun[othercase]{f}{\rn}{\rm[1]}

\end{document}
```

This example works fine, e.g, `$\fun[\omega]{\rn}{\rn[1]}$`.

If I use `$f$` function like this `$\fun[o]{f}{\rn}{\rn[m]}$`,

but I expect to use a function called `$f\colon\rn\rightarrow\rn[m]$`.

## Update

I tried to construct the command like this:

```
\newcommand{\fun}[5][default]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{
        {default}{
            \IfEqcase{#2}{
                {f}{#2\colon\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}}
                {g}{#2\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}}
            }
        }
        {other}{
            {}{#3\colon #4 \rightarrow #5}
        }
    }
}
```

Because I don't want lost the default options with `f` (`f\colon\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}`) and `g` (`g\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}`) respectively.

I see that I need one optional argument inside other optional argument.

## Source

I use this idea for create the command.

- [How to make a command with three optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257307/how-to-make-a-command-with-three-optional-arguments)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your question would be clearer if you completed the example so it was a complete document showing the problem, but you say in comments that `$\fun[\omega]{\rn}{\rn[1]}$` is fine, but it gives a runaway argument error.

Comment: if you really want three *optionsl* arguments (as the question states in the text), please add "optional" to the question title.  that will make it much more clear and obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can expect that a macro defined with one optional and two mandatory arguments will accept three mandatory arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I expected the deleted code when I edited, I'm sorry. I hope that the example is clear.

Comment: Why is this unexpected? Your first example is `\fun` with the first argument set to f. That is defined to expand to `\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}`. The second and third arguments are `\rn`s but they just get discarded. It's not clear why that is surprising, or what you want!

Comment: I want to use obtain a command correct the following behavior:

When I use the letter f, I can obtain the first order f\colonA\toB or f\colon\someset\to\otherset.

That's all

Comment: If you uncomment the line you say you want  you get an error that there is missing `$` as you have omitted the `$` if you surround the expression with `$` you get the error `! Class memoir Error: Font command \rm is not supported.` because `\rm` is not defined to do anything. perhaps you intended `\rn` but neither of those errors are comnnected with your macros at all.

Comment: Your edit is still not clear.  Your defined command looks like it would work with `\fun{f}{ignored}{ignored}{ignored}`, `\fun{g}{ignored}{ignored}{ignored}`, and `\fun[other]{ignored}{h}{\rn}{\rn}`.  How are you wanting to use it that it's not working?

Comment: It's me tried to write a command that works. Please, see in pseudocode:

1) \fun[d]{f} works for f

2) \fun[d]{g} works for g

3) \fun[o]{symbolforfunction}{inputset}{outputset} works for any function

Comment: You want canned text 1 if some argument is 'f'; canned text 2 is that argument is 'g'; and non-canned text using the other arguments otherwise?

Answer (score 2):

It's very unclear to me what you are trying to do here, or why (given the output you expect) you have defined `\fun` as you do.

Trace the expansion (use `\tracingmacros=1` if it helps, though there's a lot of junk from xstring):

- You call `\fun[f]{\rn}{\rn[m]}`
- After dealing with the optional argument, this boils down to using a command which has the template `\fun[#1]{#2}{#3}`. In your first example these `#1=f`, `#2=\rn` and `#3=`rn[m]`.
- Within `\fun` the first thing you do is use a case statement to consider the optional argument `#1`. The first line matches if `#1` is `f`, which it is.
- That line is therefore expanded, to `\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}`
- Since you haven't asked `\fun` to do anything with `#2` and `#3` in such a case, they just disappear, like any other unused argument.

What I don't understand is why you have this definition of `\fun` if you want what you say you want: I can't understand why you are looking at the first optional argument at all. Looks to me like you just want:

```
\newcommand{\fun}[3]{%
  \ensuremath{#1:#2#3}}
```

And then use it as `\fun{f}{\rn}{\rn[m]}`

Comment: Sorry, but I want to preserve this two options for f and g cases and don't generate conflict when I use f with other sets, predefined above

Comment: I don't think any of us can understand what you actually want! The best thing would be to give two or three examples: *this* input should produce *that* result. At the moment you seem to want the same input to produce different results depending on some criterion that you have not explained. It's quite clear that you **cannot** get what you want using your code.

Comment: I think we have already found a solution. Thank you for your contribution, my friend.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

If you uncomment the line you say you want  you get an error that there is missing `$` as you have omitted the `$` if you surround the expression with `$` you get the error `! Class memoir Error: Font command \rm is not supported.` because `\rm` is not defined to do anything. perhaps you intended `\rn` but neither of those errors are comnnected with your macros at all.

I do not see why you are using the test in `\fun` where it is not doing anything useful (in the first two cases it means you discard the arguments??) the xstring test isn't doing much in `\rn` either (only the test for 1, omitting the superscript, is doing anything useful) but I left that.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\rn}[1][n]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{\mathbb{R}}%
        {2}{\mathbb{R}^{2}}%
        {3}{\mathbb{R}^{3}}%
        {n}{\mathbb{R}^{n}}
        {#1}{\mathbb{R}^{#1}}
        % You can add a finite number of more cases :)
   }%
}%

\newcommand{\fun}[3][f]{%
        #1\colon #2\rightarrow #3
}

\begin{document}

If I use $f$ function like this $\fun[f]{\rn}{\rn[m]}$,

but I expect to use a function called $f\colon\rn\rightarrow\rn[m]$.

This example works fine, e.g, $\fun[\omega]{\rn}{\rn[1]}$ but I want to use 
this command

$\fun[f]{\rn}{\rn[1]}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, I notice that I don't want to lose the default commands for f and g functions, you answer is clear but I want to create other option inside. Thank you.

Comment: @Oromion sorry I do not understand your comment at all, you had defined `\fun` to take three arguments but in most cases two of them were mandatory but not used, why is that useful? I can not guess what you wanted the command to do that is different to the code I show here, sorry. I have not lost any defaults here, the command has one optional argument defaulting to f just as you defined it.

Answer (score 0):

In this small example, I created two subcommands, the first one I called default and the second general, I used the [xstring](https://ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package the command `\IfEqCase`, but I have obtained some unexpected results, I hope it helps you.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\comdefault}[1][f]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{
        {f}{\ensuremath{f\colon\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}}}
        {g}{\ensuremath{g\colon\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}}}}%[other case]
}

\newcommand{\comgeneral}[3]{
    \ensuremath{#1\colon#2\rightarrow#3}
}

\newcommand{\comfinal}[4][default]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{
        {default}{\comdefault[#2]}
        {general}{\comgeneral{#2}{#3}{#4}}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item The function $g$ is \comdefault[g]. % Subcommand 1
    \item The function $f$ is \comgeneral{f}{X}{Y}. % Subcommand 2
    \item La función $h_1$ does not work correctly %\comfinal{h_1}. %{}%{}{}
    \item La función $h_2$ does not work correctly either. %\comfinal{h_2}{}
    \item The function $h_3$ works \comfinal[general]{X}{Y}{Z}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```