# How to interpret the contents of a macro as key=value assignment for pgfkeys

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

Based on [this pgfkeys method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/831), I tried to collect options in a macro for later re-use:

```
% Set options for a photo
% #1 = options, #2 = photo name, i.e. June
\newcommand\SetPhoto[2][]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname #2photoOptions\endcsname{#1}%
}

\pgfkeys{
  /Photo/.is family, /Photo,
    defaults/.style = {bleed = 0pt,},
    bleed/.initial = {},
}

% Place the photo using eariler options
% #1 = photo name
\newcommand\DoPhoto[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{
    /Photo, defaults,
    \csname #1photoOptions\endcsname,
  }%

  % ...
  % ... deal with placing the photo, \includegraphics and so on
  % ...
}
```

And use it like this:

```
% somewhere early in the document
\SetPhoto[bleed=3mm]{June}
\SetPhoto[bleed=5mm]{July}

% typeset the photos with the given options 
\DoPhoto{June}
\DoPhoto{July}
```

But pgfkeys sees the whole content of the macro (`bleed=3mm`) as a key:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/Photo/bleed=3mm' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

How to interpret the contents of a macro as key=value assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have to expand the control sequence inside the definition with any kind of `\expandafter,\edef` combo, or you use keys for everything. Since the control sequence holds the style keys there is no point on defining a macro. Instead use the key system and dump the options in a style:

```
\newcommand*\SetPhoto[2][]{\pgfkeys{/Photo/#2photoOptions/.style={#1}}
```

and then when you have

```
\newcommand*\DoPhoto[1]{\pgfkeys{/Photo, defaults,#1photoOptions}}
```

or the expanded version of this definition.

Comment: The problem is that the key in `\SetPhoto` will be local, and `\DoPhoto` won't see it. I tried expanding the macro, but I didn't have success with that either.

Comment: @Nyiti Shouldn't be local. Are you setting the key in some environment?

Comment: you're right, it compiles in a separate mwe. I'm messing it up somewhere else.

Comment: I need this in a different situation where passing through a macro is really what I need. I cannot devise the "any kind of `\expandafter`,`\edef` combo". Can you give me any hint about it?

Answer (score 2):

Based on percusse's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys{
  /Photo/.is family, /Photo,
    defaults/.style = {bleed = 0pt,},
    bleed/.initial = {},
}

\newcommand\SetPhoto[2][]{\pgfkeys{/Photo/#2opts/.style={#1}}}

\newcommand\DoPhoto[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/Photo, defaults, #1opts}%
  % suppose it was an image...
  \hskip -\pgfkeysvalueof{/Photo/bleed}%
  \frame{#1}%
}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

% somewhere early in the document
\SetPhoto{May}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=3mm]{June}%
\SetPhoto[bleed=5mm]{July}%

% typeset the photos with the given options 

\DoPhoto{May}

\DoPhoto{June}

\DoPhoto{July}

\end{document}
```

[image: photo placeholders]