# Boxing and coloring background of text

Tags: boxes

how can I easily make a box like this, set its width and the white border around it?

[image]

(Ignore the text inside.)

Comment: Welcome! Have a look at mdframed as well :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is way with `tcolorbox` and the `borderline=` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0.5pt, 
    colback=red!30!white,   
    borderline={0.5pt}{-2pt}{black,solid} % 0.5pt linewith, -2pt outside, black solid linestyle
 ]
\blindtext
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic implementation that uses a [key-value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/5764) approach to setting the `width` and `b`ack`g`round colour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,keyval}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\makeatletter
\definecolor{pinkish}{rgb}{0.96,0.80,0.80}
\newlength{\@mcb@width}
\define@key{mcb}{bg}{\def\@mcb@bg{#1}}
\define@key{mcb}{width}{\setlength\@mcb@width{#1}}
\newcommand{\mycolorbox}[2][]{{%
  \setkeys{mcb}{width=0.5\linewidth,bg=pinkish,#1}%
  \fbox{\colorbox{\@mcb@bg}{\begin{minipage}{\@mcb@width}
    \strut#2\strut
  \end{minipage}}}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycolorbox{something}

\mycolorbox[width=.3\linewidth]{something}

\mycolorbox[bg=blue!40!white]{something}

\mycolorbox[bg=green!15!white,width=.7\linewidth]{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

`\strut`s are used in an attempt to [achieve a more consistent baseline height/depth at the top/bottom of the `minipage` construction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34971/5764).

One could also use a `tabular` construction, if needed.