# tcolorbox use for theorems

Tags: boxes, tcolorbox, typography

I do really need your help.

following this post : [boxing and coloring my theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411779/boxing-and-coloring-my-theorem/411786?noredirect=1#comment1028226_411786)

I read this [document](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf).  I think this package have everything I need, but I don't know how to write it exactly :/

I searched how to do the following things :

I need to define a few boxes that will be the shell of the theorems, the examples and the exercices of my document. I want to define a structure at the beginning of the document to use it in the rest of it.

I would like to have my theorems in a red box, the exemples with just a line on the left and that they are a little shifted on the right (not on the same vertical axis as the rest) , the exercice in an orange box with the solution following the same typography as the examples (meaning shifted on the right and with a line on the left).

*To do so, I find this in the document :*  **first, i need to create some boxes like this:**

[image]

the thing that is the most similar i ve done is this :

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!45!white, title = Myboxy}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
This is my own box.
\end{mybox}
```

but it doesn't suit me because I want the title to be in another box like on the image...they explain the options on page 155 but I don't understand what the heck is going on... ^^'

**Moreover, I heard that usually they are problems with counting the theorems.** How do you manage this ? It is not crucial but it would be great if I have a counter for every chapter for the theorems and the exercices.

**p46, they are talking about toggling, "Toggle Left and Right", I think that is the option to shift a box in a direction ? I don't understand how they implement this option in the options of the box :/** and moreover, I need also a line on the left, that is what i found :

**p178 they are talking about border line...**
about border lines I found the perfect example in an other package and it looks like this :
[image]

The S one suits perfectly... 
I want the line to take the color violet and green. How can I do this using tcolorbox?

thank you very much, i would be great if someone have the answer to this question. I'm struggling with this since a few days and I really don't how to do this.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400957/how-make-framed-blocks-in-beamer/400987#400987 could help

Comment: In this answer you'll find these theorem styles defined with `tcolorbox`. All lines are black, but it's easy to change the color. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236230/1952