# Allow for leading space in use of pgfkeys

Tags: spacing, macros, pgfkeys, options

`pgfkeys` seems to have no problem with leading spaces. For instance, adapting the solution from [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301), I can define a key `text=` as follows:

```
\pgfkeys{ % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
    /MyMacro/.is family,
    /MyMacro,
    default MyMacro options/.style={  % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
        text={},
    },
    text/.store in = \Text,
}
```

and things work as desired. However, when I attempt to actuall *use* this key I need to supress the leading space:

```
\MyMacro{% <-- How to eliminate requiring this?
    text={Some Text},
}%
```

I would be nice to not require that additional `%`. Is there an easy to way to do that?

### Note:

- This a only a *minor* inconvenience, so easy to live with, but thought I should ask in case I am missing something.  Also, options in `tikzpicture` and `axis` environment don't have these issue, so am thinking that there is some switch that can resolve this.

  However, no need to spend too much valuable procastingting time solving this issue -- plus I have a few other real problems realted to `pgfkeys` so you can procastinate on those if desired (just gotta build the MWE).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{ % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301
    /MyMacro/.is family,
    /MyMacro,
    default MyMacro options/.style={  % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
        text={},
    },
    text/.store in = \Text,
}

\newcommand{\MyMacro}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/MyMacro/.cd, default MyMacro options, #1}%
    \Text
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyMacro{% <-- How to eliminate requiring this?
        text={Some Text},
    }%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition text of `\MyMacro` has a space between the comma and the following `#1`.
You deliver another space when supplying the argument to `\MyMacro`.
Thus there will be two consecutive space tokens while it seems that *pgfkeys* does "expect" at most one space token.

Therefore I suggest removing the space between the comma and `#1` within the definition text of `\MyMacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{ % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
    %% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301
    /MyMacro/.is family,
    /MyMacro,
    default MyMacro options/.style={  % <-- NOTE: Space here is ok
        text={},
    },
    text/.store in = \Text,
}

\newcommand{\MyMacro}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/MyMacro/.cd, default MyMacro options,#1}%<-space between comma and #1 removed
    \Text
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyMacro{
        text={Some Text},
    }%
\end{document}
```