# Define Command/Macro with boolean flag

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'd love to have a command with a boolean flag. That flag is supposed to be used in a conditional statement.

I'd love to have something like this:

```
\command             -> false
\command[flag=false] -> false

\command[flag]       -> true
\command[flag=true]  -> true
```

In the definition I'd have a switch like this:

```
\iftrue{#flag} true \else false \fi
```

Comment: Have a look at the key value packages we recommended yesterday, e.g. pgfkeys. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values

Comment: that for example is exactly how `clip` works in `\includegraphics`  (defined using the `keyval` package)

Comment: Well, I see how I could create a value, but not how I could handle the `\command[flag]` case...

Comment: What's wrong with `\newif\ifflag`, `\flagtrue`, `\flagfalse`, `\ifflag..\else..\fi`?

Comment: @UlrichDiez nothing other that I know nothing about conditionals in LaTeX

Comment: @BrainStone `\newif\ifflag` creates a new `\if...`-conditional. Calling `\flagtrue` causes `\ifflag..\else..\fi` to henceforth go the `\if..`-branch. Calling `\flagfalse` causes `\ifflag..\else..\fi` to henceforth go the `\else..`-branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an advanced key-value interface, here is `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\command}{O{}}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { brainstone/command }
   {
    flag=false, % initialize to false
    #1
   }
  %
  \bool_if:NTF \l_brainstone_command_flag_bool
   {
    The ~ flag ~ is ~ set ~ to ~ true
   }
   {
    The ~ flag ~ is ~ set ~ to ~ false
   }
 }

\keys_define:nn { brainstone/command }
 {
  flag .bool_set:N = \l_brainstone_command_flag_bool,
  flag .default:n  = true,
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\command           \ $\to$ false

\command[flag=false] $\to$ false

\command[flag]       $\to$ true

\command[flag=true]  $\to$ true

\end{document}
```

[image]

The flag will remain set in the current scope.

Comment: A bit more complicated than I thought, but works like a charm! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `expkv` with the `expkv-def` front end.

This solution uses a group to keep the effects of the key=value argument local. If using a group isn't possible for other reasons you could as well set `flag=false` before evaluating `#1` in the `\ekvset`-call.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{brainstone}
  {
    boolTF flag = \brainstoneFlag
  }

\NewDocumentCommand\brainstone{O{}}
  {%
    \begingroup % group keeping the changes local
      \ekvset{brainstone}{#1}%
      The flag is set to \brainstoneFlag{true}{false}.%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\brainstone

\brainstone[flag=false]

\brainstone[flag]

\brainstone[flag=true]
\end{document}
```

[image]