# Setup override pgfkeys options

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I have a custom macro `\MyMacro` that uses `pgfkeys` to specify three things:

1. The `text=` to be output
2. The `color=` of the text
3. The `punctuation=` to place at the end.

I would like to define the macro `\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions` to be able to specify *override* options for the *next* invocation of `\MyMacro`.

So, for instance with

```
\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions{color=magenta, punctuation={.}}
```

I would like

```
\MyText{text={xxx}, color=brown, puncutation={:}}
```

to be treated as if this was invoked as

```
\MyText{text={xxx}, color=magenta, punctuation={.}}}
```

That is, the options `color=magenta` and `punctuation={!}` from `\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions` override any specified options, and override any default setting of those options.

My attempt below *almost* works in that the override `puncutaion=` gets applied, but `color=` does not.  Furthermore, the options do not seem to be reset between subsequent invocations of `\MyMacro`.

`\MyMacro` invokes

```
\pgfkeys{/MyMacro/.cd, default MyMacro options,#1,adjust MyMacro options}%
```

where `#1` is the user specified options and `adjust MyMacro options` are set via a call to `\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions`.  My assumption here is the last setting of the key overrides any previous setting, so that anything in `adjust MyMacro options` would override any default setting and any user specified setting.

The MWE below yields:

[image]

whereas I desire the code to produce:

[image]

### Note:

- This particular macro has a very large number of options that I may want to override, so am hoping that I don't need to do something specfic for *each* particular option.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{ 
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301
    /MyMacro/.is family,
    /MyMacro,
    %% Numerous other keys can be set here.
    default MyMacro options/.style={ 
        text={},
        color=blue,
        punctuation={.},
    },
    adjust MyMacro options/.style={},
    text/.store in = \Text,
    color/.store in = \Color,
    punctuation/.store in = \Punctuation,
}
\newcommand{\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{ 
        /MyMacro,
        default MyMacro options/.style/.expand once={ 
            #1,%
        }
    }
}%


\newcommand{\MyMacro}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/MyMacro/.cd, default MyMacro options,#1,adjust MyMacro options}%
    \textcolor{\Color}{\Text}\Punctuation%
    \SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions{}% Reset for next use
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyMacro{%
        text={This should be in red and end with a period},
        color=red,
    }%
    
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
    %% For the next use of this, I want to fix SOME options independent
    %% of how the next invocation of \MyMacro sets them.
    \SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions{%
        color=magenta,
        punctuation={!},
    }%
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \MyMacro{%
        text={This should be magenta and end with an exclamation},
        color=brown,
    }%
    
    \MyMacro{%  Back to default case
        text={This should be in blue and end with a period},
    }%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change `adjust MyMacro options`, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{ 
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34318/4301
    /MyMacro/.is family,
    /MyMacro,
    %% Numerous other keys can be set here.
    default MyMacro options/.style={/MyMacro/.cd,
        text={},
        color=blue,
        punctuation={.},
    },
    adjust MyMacro options/.style={},
    text/.store in = \Text,
    color/.store in = \Color,
    punctuation/.store in = \Punctuation,
}
\newcommand{\SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{ 
        /MyMacro/adjust MyMacro options/.style={
        /MyMacro/.cd,#1,%
        }
    }
}%


\newcommand{\MyMacro}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/MyMacro/.cd, default MyMacro options,#1,adjust MyMacro options}%
    \textcolor{\Color}{\Text}\Punctuation%
    \SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions{}% Reset for next use
}%

\begin{document}
    \MyMacro{%
        text={This should be in red and end with a period},
        color=red,
    }%

    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------
    %% For the next use of this, I want to fix SOME options independent
    %% of how the next invocation of \MyMacro sets them.
    \SetUpMyMacroAdjustedOptions{%
        color=magenta,
        punctuation={!},
    }%
    %% ----------------------------------------------------------------

    \MyMacro{%
        text={This should be magenta and end with an exclamation},
        color=brown,
    }%

    \MyMacro{%  Back to default case
        text={This should be in blue and end with a period},
    }%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Arggh!!! I knew it had to be something obvious!!  I spent soooo much time to get to this point, only to make that typo!!

Comment: @PeterGrill I think these days are a bit crazy...

Comment: Yep, strange days indeed!!  Thanks for your help.