# How to construct a macro with key=value by \pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, key-value

I just learn `\pgfkeys`, but don't quite understand how to use it for making a macro with `key=value` options.

I'd like to give the following simple example as a practice to show my idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycolorbox}[1][]{
  \pgfkeys{
  color/.initial=red,
  text/.initial=some text,
  #1,
  exe/.code=\colorbox{color}{text}
}
}
\begin{document}
\mycolorbox[color=blue, text=This is a practice.]
\end{document}
```

This does not work. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values/45667)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to define your own namespace for keys and separate key definition from usage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/lyl/mycolorbox/.cd, % define your own space
  color/.store in=\mycolorboxcolor,
  text/.store in=\mycolorboxtext,
  color=red!40,
  text=some text,
}

\newcommand{\mycolorbox}[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/lyl/mycolorbox/.cd,#1}%
  \colorbox{\mycolorboxcolor}{\mycolorboxtext}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\mycolorbox[color=blue!20]

\mycolorbox[text=This is a practice.]

\mycolorbox[color=blue!20, text=This is a practice.]

\end{document}
```

The expl3 version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { lyl/mycolorbox }
 {
  color .tl_set:N  = \l__lyl_mycolorbox_color_tl,
  text  .tl_set:N  = \l__lyl_mycolorbox_text_tl,
  color .initial:n = red!40,
  text  .initial:n = some~text,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycolorbox}{O{}}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { lyl/mycolorbox } { #1 }
  \colorbox{\l__lyl_mycolorbox_color_tl}{\l__lyl_mycolorbox_text_tl}
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mycolorbox[color=blue!20]

\mycolorbox[text=This is a practice.]

\mycolorbox[color=blue!20, text=This is a practice.]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does that mean if I have 20 keys, then I have to use 20 macros to store them?  in an article, maybe many commands needs key=value. So many marco names are too heavy to namespace? Do I understand it right?

Comment: @lyl There is plenty of memory space for macros, don't worry.

Comment: I tried this: `\def\mycolorboxtext{aaa}\mycolorbox[color=blue!20]`, and `aaa` was typeset. Does that mean the namespace is polluted? It seems that `\begingroup...\endgroup` does not work?

Comment: @lyl I added an `expl3` version that I'd prefer. Anyway, don't do `\def\mycolorboxtext`.

Comment: If you have lots of keys, I'd go for a programmatic set up of all of them

Comment: @ Joseph Wright  Would you provide more details about your idea?

Comment: @egrg Many thanks for your solutions and suggestion!! And are there better ways to prevent those key macros from polluting namespace?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to store values is inside the key paths themselves (that doesn't mean you don't use as many commands, so this doesn't ease the namespace-heaviness).

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\pgfkeys
  {%
     /mycolorbox/.is family
    ,/mycolorbox
    ,color/.initial=blue
    ,text/.initial=some text
  }
\newcommand\mycolorbox[1][]
  {%
    \begingroup
      \pgfqkeys{/mycolorbox}{#1}%
      \colorbox
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mycolorbox/color}}
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/mycolorbox/text}}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\mycolorbox

\mycolorbox[color=red]

\mycolorbox[text=foobar]
\end{document}
```

(note: `\pgfqkeys{/<path>}{<keys>}` is the same as `\pgfkeys{/<path>/.cd,<keys>}` but faster)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. And how does `\begingroup...\endgroup` here work?

Comment: `\begingroup...\endgroup` just keeps the changes to the options local to this one command, so that the next invocation isn't dependent on the previous one. The two commands (`\begingroup` and `\endgroup`) are TeX primitives.

Comment: Oh,I see. It's the cost of non-macro to store value of keys.  Many thanks!

Comment: @lyl no, you'd do the same if you used macros to store the values. All that `\pgfkeys{/foo/bar/.initial={<value>}}` does is store the value inside a macro with a long name that is `\pgfk@/foo/bar` (slashes are part of the macro name).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just setting up a simple macro with a few keys (and that's the only interface accessing and using those keys), you could as well build your macro with `expkv-cs`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcSplit\mycolorbox
  {
     color=blue
    ,text=some text
  }
  {\colorbox{#1}{#2}}%

\begin{document}
\mycolorbox{}

\mycolorbox{color=red}

\mycolorbox{text=foobar}
\end{document}
```

(`expkv-cs` defines the macro `\mycolorbox` with a mandatory argument, if you want to use an optional one, just add a wrapper like: `\newcommand\mycolorbox[1][]{\mycolorboxSplit{#1}}` and changing the name of the macro after `\ekvcSplit` to `\mycolorboxSplit`).

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for these good solution and suggestion!