# how to ``open'' the curly bracket in a macro?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, xkeyval

In tikz, the macro `\draw` accept a optical argument of parameters separated with comma, e.g.

```
\draw[->, red] (0, 0) -- (1, 1)
```

I have a self defined macro, in which I want to pass a macro as this optional parameter, i.e. sth like

```
\def\p{->, red}
\draw[\p] (0, 0) -- (1, 1)
```

However, I get a ``` ERROR: Package pgf Error: Arrow end type ``>, red'' unknown. ```
 which is the same error with

```
\draw[{{->, red}}] (0, 0) -- (1, 1)
```

I think it is because the argument is passed as a single `character` and failed to be separated.

Is there a way to do it correctly? (i.e. "unquote" the curly bracket before passing it to the `\draw` macro.)

In my particular case, I use xkeyval package to define my macro [according to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/a-package-template-using-xkeyval). Therefore I have to pass the argument through a macro.

(Any tikz specific work around is also helpful. THX)

Comment: THX, all the solutions works for me. I have chosen the answer that is the best for my case, although other answers were actually what I was planning to look for. =D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={->, red}}` instead of a `\def` to define your own custom style to be applied:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{MyStyle/.style={->, red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[MyStyle] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \def\p{->, red}
\draw\expandafter[\p] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with etex

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
   \def\p{->, red}   
   \makeatletter
 \protected@edef\tmp{%
   \noexpand \draw[\p] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);}\tmp  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I guess that defining a new arrow style might be better.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you but `\protected@edef\tmp{` saves me in a lot of painful situations and if OP writes a package it's perhaps very useful.

Comment: Oh, yes: I've suggested a few times something of the kind.

Comment: @egreg It's difficult to understand that OP wants to use tikz with a macro and he doesn't know what is a style !

Answer (score 2):

An immediate solution to your problem is

```
\expandafter\draw\expandafter[\p]
```

But if you want to use this systematically, it will become awkward.

Anyway, whatever you do you need to make sure the content of `[]` is expanded before `\draw` is executed.

Comment: Yes, this (order of expansion) is what I was confusing about. THX.