# Not getting xkeyval to work (as intended) for a simple custom command

Tags: xkeyval

I'm trying the use the `xkeyval` package to define a very simple command using keys. However, I'm utterly confused by its behavior, and the package documentation is not exactly helpful either. Here's a MWE with what I wanted to achieve (expected) and what I actually got. Why is this happening and what do I need to do to get the result I'm after? I've also consulted: [How to create a command with key values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/14120) and: [A package template using xkeyval?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13270/a-package-template-using-xkeyval) without any luck

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key[]{fam}{foo}[XX]{#1}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][]{%
   \begingroup
   \setkeys[]{fam}{#1}
   ``Using the macro: \fam@foo ''
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Example where I hoped to get the default value (XX)
\mycommand % Expected: "Using the macro XX" - Got: "Using the macro"

% Example where I hoped to override the default value
\mycommand[foo=YY] % Expected: "Using the macro YY" - Got: YY "Using the macro"


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
\define@key[]{fam}{foo}[XX]{<code>}
```

you are essentially doing

```
\def\fam@foo#1{<code>}
```

In your case you have

```
\def\fam@foo#1{#1}
```

which is confirmed if I change the code into

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][]{%
   \begingroup
   \setkeys[]{fam}{#1}
   \texttt{\meaning\fam@foo}\\
   ``Using the macro: \fam@foo ''
   \endgroup
}
```

getting

[image]

When you do `\setkeys[]{fam}{foo}` you're doing `\fam@foo{YY}` which, by definition, expands to `YY`. Later, you're doing `\fam@foo'` and this expands to `'`.

If you want to save a value, you have to say something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key[]{fam}{foo}[XX]{\def\fam@foo@toks{#1}}
\setkeys[]{fam}{foo} % initialize
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][]{%
   \begingroup
   \setkeys[]{fam}{#1}
   ``Using the macro: \fam@foo@toks ''
   \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mycommand

\mycommand[foo=YY]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative is to use `\define@cmdkey`, that does the above using `\cmdfam@foo` as container.

```
\define@cmdkey[]{fam}{foo}{}
\setkeys[]{fam}{foo=XX} % initialize
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][]{%
   \begingroup
   \setkeys[]{fam}{#1}
   ``Using the macro: \cmdfam@foo''
   \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I'm now even more confused. It appears that I simply don't understand how this package is even supposed to be used. In particular, why is not the method which is specified in the documentation of `xkeyval` (Sec 3.1) not working? And what does `toks` even mean? Is it just arbitrary? And why do I have to specify even more `\def`'s? I thought that was supposed to be handled by the `\define@key` command? And why do I have to specify default values with an extra call to `\setkeys` when you are supposed to supply that in `\define@key`?

Comment: `toks` is just arbitrary; use `\define@cmdkey` if you want a “uniform” name. The default value is used when the key is *called* without a value.

Comment: While the `cmdkey` example appeared cleaner, how do I specify functions of the input with it? I.e. if I want to take in the value of `foo` (#1) and make it bold (say). And what do you mean by *called*? I'm sorry for being so dense, but it seems that there is something really fundamental I'm not getting here...

Comment: @hakoja `Using the macro: \textbf{\cmdfam@foo}` with `\define@cmdkey`; or `\define@key[]{fam}{foo}{\def\cmdfam@foo{\textbf{#1}}}` and then `Using the macro \cmdfam@foo`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your patience. I'm accepting your answer since it works, but unfortunately I don't really understand it at all. It's just so confusing that I don't see how this usage corresponds to the way it appears we are supposed to use this package in the documentation.