# Map multiple different key-value pairs to the same behaviour

Tags: pgfkeys, key-value

I've been typesetting a competition paper using the `exam` class, which has options for nice headers and cover pages.

Now, this competition has two different age categories, 'Junior' and 'Senior', and three different rounds: 'MCQ', 'Team', and 'Observation'. I'd like the title page and the headers to all reflect any one of the six resulting combinations by specifying options to a command, in the manner of key-value pairs. For instance, `\setcatround[category=jnr, round=mcq]` should set these variables appropriately, and these should be reflected in *both* the header and the title/cover page of the exam.

I have selected `pgfkeys` as my key-value package of choice. I passed over `keyval`, `xkeyval`, and `kvoptions`, because I find their syntax to be *particularly* esoteric compared to the relative straightforwardness of `pgfkeys`. Furthermore, Mr Wright (of `siunitx` fame) recommends `pgfkeys` or `l3keys` versus the others, [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13273/174314).

An M(N)WE [minimum (not) working example]:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgfkeys} 

\pgfkeys{
    /ac/.is family, /ac,
    category/.estore in = \category,
    round/.estore in = \round
}

\newcommand*{\setcatround}[1]{\pgfqkeys{/ac}{#1}}

\setcatround{category=senior, round=mcq}

\header{My Exam}{}{\category{} \round{} Round}

\title{Competition}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\LARGE{\category{} \round{} Round}
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\end{document}
```

Now, this MWE works *okay*, but my idea was to:

1. Print the competition Category And Round In Title Case, like so: `Junior MCQ Round`, or `Senior Team Round`;
2. Print the category and round *together* using only *one* command; for instance, `\catround{}` should yield `Junior MCQ Round` when the appropriate options are set with `\setcatround{...}`;
3. Allow users to specify either of `jnr`/`junior`, or `snr`/`senior` and output the appropriate results.

How might I go about specifying these, and possibly make it easily extensible for any future additions?

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `.is choice` key handler, which is documented in [PGF Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 88.4.5:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{pgfkeys} 

\pgfkeys{
  /ac/.cd,
  category/.is choice,
  category/jun/.code={\edef\category{Junior}},
  category/snr/.code={\edef\category{Senior}},
  % you can define similar choice-keys for "round"
  round/.estore in = \round
}

\newcommand*{\setcatround}[1]{\pgfqkeys{/ac}{#1}}

\setcatround{category=snr, round=mcq}

\header{My Exam}{}{\category{} \round{} Round}

\title{Competition}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\centering
\LARGE{\category{} \round{} Round}
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\end{document}
```

[image]